# Label and caption without float

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, captions

I’d like to have an environment that works much like a float, except that it doesn’t float.

That is, in fact, I’d like to be able to define an environment that has a label and a caption.

I explicitly do **not** want to use a floating environment, though. For one thing, floats do many things fancy which I just don’t need, nor want (such as spacing) and for another, floats have their share of problems (for example consider the problem of [splitting a float between pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4590/42)).

Is there a ready-made way to achieve this? Of course, I could always write my own based on the result of the other answer, i.e. harnessing `\refstepcounter`. But I’m not sure how to use that, documentation is scarce, and I’d prefer an existing solution.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `\captionof` from either the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) or [`capt-of`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionType{mytype}[Typename][List of mytype]
\newenvironment{myenv}{}{}

\begin{document}
\listofmytypes

\section{abc}

\begin{myenv}
\captionof{mytype}{blub} something in my type
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Although redefining `\caption` inside the environment so I can use *that* instead of `\captionof` was surprisingly difficult (I suspect cross-talk between caption and hyperref). But now I can write (almost) usual code and get a caption + label.

Comment: Why not just use \captionof{figure}{blub}?  That way it will show up in the list of figures.  Nor do you need a custom environment.

Comment: Just as a small (and late) addition in case anybody stumbles across this answer: If you use a KOMA-class the `\captionof` command is already available and you don't need `caption` or `capt-of` (there are also `\captionbelowof` and `\captionaboveof`, see the scrguide)

Answer (score 18):

Redefining `\caption` inside the environment should be easy, as long as you let the caption package do the job and do not try it for yourself ;-)

Ulrikes example, modified:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionType{mytype}[Typename][List of mytype]
\newenvironment{myenv}{\captionsetup{type=mytype}}{}

\begin{document}
\listofmytypes

\section{abc}

\begin{myenv}
\caption{blub} something in my type
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant! That should indeed do the trick. Just for the record, I already got the same effect with a manual redefinition (but your code is much better, and I’ll adapt it) – what I wanted to achieve, though, is the ability to write `\caption{…}\label{…}` (in *any* order) and the code produced would put the label inside the caption, like so: `\captionof{…\label{…}}`. Surprisingly, that fails.