# Code spanning over two pages with minted, inside listing with caption

Tags: floats, page-breaking, highlighting, minted, code

I am trying using minted to display some code in my document, but the code is long and spans over two pages, this works fine, however when I place my code inside

```
\begin{listing}
  \inputminted{java}{code/JavaCode.java}
  \caption{Some caption}
  \label{label1}
\end{listing}
```

Then my code doesn't show up and I get the warning:

> LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page

I have tried using the option `H` in `listing`, but then the code shows in only one page and it doesn't fit so I only see a part of it.

I also tried with the code directly in the latex document ie:

```
\begin{listing}
  \begin{minted}{java} 
    Java code
  \end{minted}
  \caption{Some caption}
  \label{label1}
\end{listing}
```

But the same happens, any ideas?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As far as I know, this is a fundamental restriction of floats. You cannot use floats that span over more than one page so you need to remove the surrounding `listing`.

To make the caption still work, you can load the `caption` package and use the `\captionof` command instead of `\caption`:

```
\inputminted{java}{code/JavaCode.java}
\captionof{listing}{Some caption}
```

Now the caption should also appear in the `\listoflistings`.
If you want to use a label here, you need to put it *inside* the `\captionof` command:

```
\captionof{listing}{Some caption\label{lst:some-label}}
```

See also: [Question “Label and caption without float”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7210/42).

Comment: Thanks! This works. Is there a way to also add a label so I can reference it from other part of my text? Also, if I use this, then then `\listoflistings` won't list my code right?

Comment: @lander See updated answer.

Comment: `\captionof` requires an environment so this does not work correctly, see my answer.

Comment: @ms4py Is right.

Comment: I realize that minted is not really maintained anymore, but still thought I should mention that page-spanning breaks the moment you set a background colour.

Comment: Sorry, it breaks when I use `\inputminted`.

Comment: The first line of each paragraph is not indented properly when I use the `\captionof` solution.

Answer (score 32):

The suggested and accepted answer does not work correctly as the `\captionof` command requires to be inside an environment. This is pointed out in the `caption` documentation. For example in my case there was no proper vertical space after the caption.

A proper solution is to define a new environment:

```
\usepackage{caption}
% ...
\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}

\begin{code}
\begin{minted}[frame=single]{py}
def my_func(x):
    print x
\end{minted}
\caption{My Func}
\label{lst:my_func}
\end{code}
```

Comment: When I use this solution with `\inputminted`, page spanning breaks.

Comment: I am using `\inputminted` and it's running perfectly in my case. Are you sure you've included the `caption` package ?

Comment: In your example is better to use caption or captionof?

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the solution by @Konrad Rudolph to something that is simple and doesn't break anything:

```
\inputminted[linenos]{python}{code.py}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \caption{Hello.}
    \label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
```

Of course, this is going to be named and listed as a Figure, but that's not a problem for me.

Comment: You don't need to use a figure float. If `\captionof` doesn't work for you (which, weird!) you can (and should) simply use a `listing` float environment.

Comment: The `\captionof` appeared to work, until I noticed that the paragraphs don't start with the usual indentation (and are restored to normal when I removed the `\captionof`). The `listing` environment doesn't split over two pages (I haven't tried `mdframed` for breaking a `listing` environment, because according to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103471/8666, `mdframed` helps with breaking in the presence of a background color).

Comment: *No* floating environment breaks across pages. I meant using the "correct" environment to put the title in.

Comment: Interesting approach, thought its more like a very quick fix then an proper answer.

Comment: Sometimes the caption is placed on a different page.
How can we fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this kind of problem I use two listings - split in half - in combination with `\ContinuedFloat`:

```
\begin{listing}
    \ContinuedFloat*
    \begin{codeblock}{}{C}
        \cfile[lastline=33]{code/xxx.c}
    \end{codeblock}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{lst:xxx}
\end{listing}

\begin{listing}
    \ContinuedFloat
    \begin{codeblock}{}{C}
        \cfile[firstline=35]{code/xxx.c}
    \end{codeblock}
    \caption{My caption (contd.)}
\end{listing}
```

Credit goes to: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures_in_multiple_parts