# minted truncates the code if it doesn't fit into one page

Tags: page-breaking, minted

`minted` works well when the code snippet is short, or fit into one page. The problem occurs when I pasted a code snippet with several hundred lines. Sometimes it processed but the output was truncated; other times it produced a bunch of errors. And if I break it into pages, the amount of characters in each page matter, i.e. it could yield a blank page after the `\end{minted}`. For example:

```
....
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=bg,mathescape]{c++}
code here
\end{minted}
... -> a blank page sometimes appear
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=bg,mathescape]{c++}
code here
\end{minted}
....
```

Has anyone encountered this awkward behavior with `minted` package? Any idea or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, [this behaviour is known, it’s a bug](http://code.google.com/p/minted/issues/detail?id=32), and I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: I have recently converted a lot of source files to pdf using `minted` package with no problems and errors, each resulting pdf files several pages long. For each source file, a `.tex` file was generated, and the source code was inserted with `\inputminted[opts...]{c++}{file}`.

Comment: I find that the problem is not in \inputminted or \begin{minted} per se, but in the \begin{listing}. If I have a long listing inserted only using \inputminted then it works fine.

Comment: See also the comparison of `minted` to the `verbments` package, written by the `minted` maintainer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103471/8666

Comment: and a simpler, flatter, tidier, and likely more robust solution suggested here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12428/code-spanning-over-two-pages-with-minted-inside-listing-with-caption, by just placing a stand-alone caption and label after the minted code, without using any `listing` environment. [Flat is better than nested](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, this behaviour is [due to a known bug](http://code.google.com/p/minted/issues/detail?id=32). Worse, I have no idea how to fix it.

In the long run, I plan to get rid of the `fancyvrb` package altogether since strictly speaking `minted` doesn’t need the verbatim capabilities – LaTeX sequences get escaped anyway. This would lead to a lot more flexibility.

For now, though, this is unfortunately not a trivial change. If you want to get your hands dirty you can try `\let`ting `\Verbatim` and `\endVerbatim` to `\relax`, and then tinkering a bit to get the rendering right again. Disclaimer: I haven’t tried this.

Answer (score 10):

The bad behaviour of the minted package in truncating code can be prevented through the mdframed package.
Example:

```
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=black, topline=true, bottomline=true,
  leftline=false, rightline=false, backgroundcolor=yellow!20!white]
    \begin{minted}[mathescape]{c++}
        int main()
            {
                bla bla...
            }
    \end{minted}
\end{mdframed}
```

Obviously you should have package mdframed loaded in your preamble, simply by `\usepackage{mdframed}` and eventually with global options.
Even better, without pasting:

```
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=black, topline=true, bottomline=true,
  leftline=false, rightline=false, backgroundcolor=yellow!20!white]
    \inputminted[fontsize=\scriptsize, linenos, frame=lines]{c++}{path/to/your/code.cpp}
\end{mdframed}
```