# Minted split code into two pages

Tags: page-breaking, algorithms, minted

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [minted truncates the code if it doesn't fit into one page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23663/minted-truncates-the-code-if-it-doesnt-fit-into-one-page)

I am using `minted` in order to write some Objective-C code inside a report I am trying to create. I use it the following way

```
\begin{minted}[linenos, fontsize=\footnotesize,
           numbersep=5pt,
           frame=lines,
           framesep=2mm,
    bgcolor=bg]{objective-c}
 ....
  some objective-c code
 ....
\end{minted}
```

The problem is that code takes 28 lines of my page.  I have 22 available lines on one page and all the lines available from the next page. LaTeX, instead of using that 22 lines from the first page and the first 6 from the other, leaves that space empty and moves all the code to the next page.  This is a problem for me because I face this problem a lot of times and a lot of pages have large empty spaces.

Is there any way to allow or tell `minted` to split the code if possible and use all the available space?

Comment: `Splitting across pages` is listed as a `defect` issue at the minted site.  [See issue 32](http://code.google.com/p/minted/issues/detail?id=32).

Comment: Fundamentally the same question as the link I've used as a dupe: it's all to do with the face that `minted` cannot split material.