# minted vs. texments vs. verbments

Tags: listings, minted

Regarding the typesetting of syntax-colored source code, I know that [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) is inferior because it doesn't utilize a full lexer. Instead the Python-based solution is recommended. It seems there are three packages to use the Python library `pygments` instead: [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted), [`texments`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texments) and [`verbments`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbments).

Most people seem to use `minted` here. The `verbments` documentation says it aims to fix issues with `minted`.

So what are the important differences? Has someone tried all of them?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

## Comparison as of March 2013 (see updates below)

I'm somewhat familiar with all the common packages that use Pygments.  As part of writing my [`pythontex`](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex) package, I researched what had been done previously.

- `texments` is pretty basic.  It doesn't provide access to much of Pygments or `fancyvrb`'s functionality.
- `minted` provides much more complete access to Pygments and `fancyvrb`, and adds additional functionality like background colors.
- `verbments` is more recent than `minted`, which probably explains why it is apparently less popular.  The `verbments` documentation says that "the `minted` package cannot split the highlighted source code over pages."  Technically, `minted` can do that fine--the problem is with the `listing` float that `minted` provides.  (Edit: There are also page break issues when a background color is used, but those can be overcome by not using the package's `bgcolor` option and using `mdframed` or a similar package instead.)  The `verbments` solution is to allow listing numbering and captions--but without providing a *real* float (which would have to solve the page break problem).  `verbments` also provides individual highlighting styles (you can use different Pygments styles for each environment) and a few additional options that `minted` lacks.
- [`pygmentex`](https://bitbucket.org/romildo/pygmentex) is yet another Pygments package (2012-02-12).  It includes custom patches for Pygments to allow escaping to LaTeX anywhere.  That is nice, but may also make maintenance difficult as Pygments continues to develop.  (That feature has been [requested](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issue/493/optionally-enable-escaping-to-latex) in Pygments since early 2010, and is *still* open.)  `pygmentex` provides an inline command.  And it caches output.
- And finally, there's my `pythontex` package.  (First release 2012/04/27, but in development for the previous year.)  Its main purpose is to allow Python code to be included in a LaTeX document, with a means to execute the code and bring back the output.  Adding Pygments highlighting was actually something of an afterthought.  `pythontex` provides most of `minted`'s functionality, except for a few things like background colors (since these can be so easily added with packages like `mdframed`).  It caches all highlighted content, using the mechanism I'd already created for caching the output of executed code.  It also provides an inline command, allows automatic line number continuation between environments of the same language, and allows `fancyvrb` settings on a per-language basis.  Unicode is supported with the pdfTeX engine.

So this leaves us with many options for Pygments highlighting.  Caching is really important for performance, but the downside is that both my approach and the `pygmentex` approach require compiling (which saves code to an auxiliary file), running a Python script (which uses Pygments to do the highlighting, then saves the output), and compiling a second time (which brings back the highlighted output).  One of the really nice things about the `\write18` approach used by the other packages is that the highlighting is always up-to-date and only requires a single compile.  It probably wouldn't be hard to cache and keep everything up-to-date using LuaTeX.  Otherwise, I would think about `\pdfmdfivesum` (possibly with temp files), except that I don't believe XeTeX has an equivalent.  There may not be a good cross-engine alternative to the three-step process.

`pythontex` is under active development and should continue to provide Pygments highlighting for the foreseable future.  While the focus is access to Python, I'm in the midst of a major refactoring that should allow the package to be extended for arbitrary languages, with only a few dozen lines of code needed per extension.  The disadvantage of all this is that `pythontex` isn't quite as nimble as a highlighting-only package.

**Edit:** After corresponding with Konrad Rudolph, I have decided to maintain `minted`.  Development will be at https://github.com/gpoore/minted.

## Update from July 2016

**As of mid-2016, `minted` will typically be the best option, unless you need specific features in `pythontex` or one of the other packages.**

Since 2013, `texments` and `verbments` are unchanged, at least on CTAN.  `pygmentex` has been updated as of May 2015; based on the [commit history](https://bitbucket.org/romildo/pygmentex/commits/), there don't appear to have been any major changes.

Since taking over `minted` development, I have added several major features.

- Caching. `minted` performs all highlighting in a single compile, caching highlighted code for future runs. The cache is automatically cleaned as long as the `.aux` file isn't deleted. The cache can be "frozen" for use in situations in which `-shell-escape` isn't available (many `minted`-related things shouldn't be edited in such a situation, since it isn't possible to update the cache).
- A command for inline code, `\mintinline`.
- Unicode support with pdfTeX.
- Arbitrary escapes to LaTeX using the `escapeinside` option from Pygments 2.0+ (but note that this [can be fragile](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/1118/escapeinside-is-fragile-with-some-lexers) depending on how Pygments tokenizes).
- Automatic line breaking at spaces, between all characters, before or after user-specified characters, between space-separated tokens, or between all tokens.
- `bgcolor` compatible with page breaks.

I have recently separated most of the line-breaking code, and some additional extensions to `fancyvrb`, into a new package called [`fvextra`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fvextra).  The next versions of `minted` and `pythontex` will both require `fvextra`; these versions will be on CTAN before the end of July 2016.  This will leave `minted` and `pythontex` with mostly identical features, although `minted` will still have the advantage of `bgcolor`, token-based line breaking, and a few Pygments options in the immediate future.  `pythontex` may still have a speed advantage in some cases, mostly when a lot of highlighted code is modified between compiles, but that should typically be minimal.

Comment: In my recent `feynmp-auto` package I used `\pdfmdfivesum` for avoiding running Metapost if the file didn't change. You can have a look at how it's done; however XeLaTeX hasn't the feature.

Comment: [minted v2.0](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) adds caching capability as well as inline highlighting.

Comment: Since the answer were given some years have passed. How does it look today? Is minted still preferable? Especially the escape from pygments to LaTeX (as proposed for pygmentex) is of interest to me. Should I start a bounty, open new question? Thanks for the review.

Comment: @math I've added an update for July 2016.

Comment: Any alternative to minted?  Minted lacks of captions and some important things. In order to have it you need to write quite a lot of code.

Comment: @skan `minted` provides a `listing` environment for creating floats with captions and labels. If you want a more compact way to use the `listing` environment, you can always create your own custom environment for that.

Comment: @G.Poore We had a question on [Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6745/7) asking about packages for code formatting in Latex. They mentioned having tried to use `minted`, but ran into issues when submitting to a chemical journal. I mention it here rather than a GitHub issue since I'm not sure if its something that can be fixed from the package side or if its the publishers mishandling the documents.

Comment: @Tyberius Publishers may have a range of restrictions on the LaTeX packages they allow for a variety of reasons. If it's just a matter of a publisher not allowing `-shell-escape`, then the `minted` package option `frozencache` may be a possibility. If the publisher just doesn't permit certain packages or custom macros, then there's really not much that can be done. Between `-shell-escape` and `frozencache`, `minted` is probably already providing all of the possibilities that are really practical. Pandoc LaTeX output with included highlighting macros might sometimes be an alternative.

Answer (score 29):

Current status: `minted` maintenance has been handed over to Geoffrey Poore.

<del>`minted` is essentially unmaintained at this point.</del> I tried fixing as many bugs as possible but two things are getting in the way:

1. I don’t have time for side-projects any more. This is unfortunate. In fact, I developed minted mainly for my own master thesis and ended up not using it there due to the fact that some tedious things remained unfixed.
2. Many interesting changes, among them the two most important ones (inline code highlighting, performance improvement via caching and change tracking) would ideally require changes in the upstream Pygments code base, and so far these changes (which have been submitted as patches to Pygments) have not been integrated.

I don’t know how (if) `verbments` works around this limitation – maybe they are maintaining their own branch of the Pygments project and don’t care for compatibility, or they’re performing some interesting parsing work in LaTeX itself. Either way I applaud the effort. I’d have preferred it if they had built on top of `minted` (to avoid duplicating work and having several projects doing the same thing) but then I also started my own package instead of building on top of `texments` so I understand the motivation behind this.