# Prevent caption to appear on separate page

Tags: page-breaking, captions, environments, minted

I'm using a custom listing environment which does not float taken from
[Code spanning over two pages with minted, inside listing with caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53540/13971).
The caption is done with the `caption` package.

The problem is that under certain circumstances the caption is on another page than the complete listing. Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

**Update** [Here](https://gist.github.com/2965182) is the minimal example. Just to clarify again: It is allowed to have pagebreaks in the code, but not between code and caption. So in the example the caption should either be also on page 1 or on page 2 there should be some lines of code.

Comment: An example of what you've got so far would be useful.

Comment: Should page breaks inside the code be allowed or not? If not than simply wrap the whole thing in a `{minipage}{\textwidth}` environment. Otherwise try a `\nopagebreak` macro before `\caption`. Note that listings should AFAIK have the caption on top not below.

Comment: The environment must not float. But if you are sure about placing the captions at the top, this would solve the problem. ;-)

Comment: About an example: After an additional paragraph the problem does not exist for now, but I didn't want to check every listing before I can release my writings.

Comment: @Martin minted unfortunately never breaks pages. I haven’t found a reliable way to ensure that the caption is on the same page myself. For my master thesis I inserted manual page breaks to make it flow properly. Admittedly an ad-hoc solution. `\nopagebreak` does *not* work. // CORRECTION: I just remembered that I didn’t use minted in my master thesis (shame on me …).

Comment: `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} <minted+caption> \end{minipage}` is then the way to go.

Comment: `minted` allows breaks. But `\nopagebreak` does not work. I want to allow page breaks within the code (so the `minipage` environment is no solution) but not at the end of the code before the caption.

Comment: @ms4py: Your bounty isn't helpful. A minimal working example is helpful!

Comment: @ms4py Your bounty will most probably be lost, as nobody can really guess what you're doing. Rather than offering a bounty you had better providing an example. Notice that the author of `minted` did make a comment here and even he didn't have many clues for answering.

Comment: Added the example.

Answer (score 1):

Things you can try:

- Wrap the part of the environment that shouldn't experience a break in a `minipage` environment. Use `\vspace{-\baselineskip}`s at will.
- Include the `needspace` package and then use `\needspace{20\baselineskip}` before the caption, where 20 is the number of lines your caption is long.
- Plaster your code or macros with `\nopagebreak[4]`s all over the place (although you mentioned that this doesn't work so just sayin').
- Use manual `\pagebreak`s
- [STFTeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=prevent%20pagebreak) and see if you can find something that can be applied to your problem as well.

Comment: Just to make it clear (again): Pagebreaks should be allowed, but **not** between the end of the listing and the caption. I try to make an example.

Comment: Ok I see I had to restate the first point. What's with the rest?

Comment: It should be a general solution, so the length of the source code is dynamic. I'm not sure how the rest of the points can apply in this case. I added an example, see the answer.

Comment: I see, tough one. You have a kind of verbatim environment, every interruption of the environment is marked by horizontal bars and `fancyvrb` does some dark sorcery to prevent anything from standing in the same line as the end of the environment. That package is your enemy, not necessarily `minted`.

Comment: So? No further idea? :(

Comment: No sorry, what `fancyvrb` does is beyond my TeX prowess :/