# Caption and label on Minted code

Tags: captions, labels, minted

I want to add a caption and label on a Minted source code so I can reference it, similarly to what you can do to figures.

In Minted manual it says I can use the listing environment, which allows to use both caption and label, the problem is that listings creates a float and only allows to use one page. My source code is long and spans on two pages.

**How can I add caption and label but still be able to use two pages?**

Comment: A solution is described in minted docs.  **8 FAQ and Troubleshooting**, _I need a listing environment that supports page breaks_.  It has a link to [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53540/10742).

Comment: Thank you @ArashEsbati, it works now but the caption shows like this: `Listing 1: MY_LABEL`. Is there a way to change from `Listing 1` to `Source Code 1`?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can define a non-floating environment which can break over pages and put the `minted` environment in that one.  This is a documented feature:

> **8 FAQ and Troubleshooting**
>
> - **I need a listing environment that supports page breaks**. The built-in    listing environment is a standard float; it doesn’t
>     support page    breaks. You will probably want to define a new
>     environment for long    floats.  [...]
>     With the caption package, it
>     is best to use minted’s    newfloat package option.  See
>     https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53540/10742

Loading `minted.sty` with `newfloat` option enables you to customize the `listing` environment, `caption.sty` offers `\captionof` for captions outside floating environments.  Check their docs for further (plenty of) options.

Putting it together:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage{caption}

\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{name=Source Code}

\begin{document}
\begin{code}
\captionof{listing}{My C-Code}
\label{code:c-code}
\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{code}

Reference to \ref{code:c-code}.  

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Why do you use captionof instead of caption?

Comment: @skan - For 2 reasons: 1) I use `\caption` in floating env's, this is a matter of taste. 2) My editor understands the first floating type argument in `\captionof` and includes the right prefix in the `\label` argument, e.g. `\label{lst:foo}` (not shown in the code above, though).

Comment: How to add location parameters like [t] to the code environment? so that it places that on the top of the page

Comment: @KennetCeleste - `code` is a non-floating environment, so you can have a listing with a page break.  This is what the question was about.  If you want a floating environment, read the `minted` manual, section 4 Floating listings.

Comment: @ArashEsbati I basically want to have something like "subfigure" for minted. 3 minted subfigures in one bigger listing. Can you help me with that? I can create a question if you can help with that.

Comment: @KennetCeleste - Creating a new question is the way to go (after searching if someone else had this request).  If not me, someone else will help.  I also think the solution is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Use figure or table block to add the source. I think it is a simple solution.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{minted}[mathescape, breaklines,frame=single, fontsize=\footnotesize]{python}
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, input_shape=(12,), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
\end{minted}
\caption{Classification model and layers}\label{code:CML}
\end{figure}
```