# Pagebreak for minted in figure

Tags: floats, page-breaking, minted

I currently have the following way of inserting code in my report, as I do not typically want pagebreaks for my code examples.

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,breaklines=true}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering

\begin{minted}{java}
Code here...
\end{minted}

   \caption{This is an example of code}
    \label{fig:codeexample}

\end{figure}
```

However I now have an example that is more than one page, and I can't get pagebreaking to work. Is there a better way of approaching this? I still want to have figure numbers as I refer to them in the report.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Using a figure seems the wrong approach, but you could use `\captionof{figure}{My caption}`. In order to give you real advice please post some more code (MWE).

Answer (score 15):

Welcome to TeX.SX!

Yes, I would indeed say there is a better way of achieving this. Well, at least in my humble opinion.

For starters, as has been mentioned by TeXnician, using a figure to contain a listing isn't really very proper. I would recommend using dedicated `listings` environments for that. After all, a figure is not the same thing as a listing.

Besides the philosophical question of whether or not one should use `figure` environments to contain listings, there is also a practical issue: A `figure` environment is a float and cannot break across pages. So I would recommend a different approach:

- Use a `listings` float for short code listings which should not break across pages.
- Create a new environment for long code listings which can break across pages. See page 32 of the `minted` package documentation, which also refers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53540/131649).

## Short Example for Showcasing the Principles

As said, we create a new environment called `longlisting` which will break across pages and can be captioned and labelled. It will also show up in the `\listoflistings`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption}
\setminted{
    linenos=true,
    autogobble,
}
% Create a new environment for breaking code listings across pages.
\newenvironment{longlisting}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
\begin{document}

\listoflistings

\section{Let Us Make Some Listings}

\begin{longlisting}
    \begin{minted}{tex}
        ... input a lot of code here ...
        ... It will break across pages ...
    \end{minted}
    \caption[Long Code Example]{A long code example which will break across pages.}
\label{lst:long}
\end{longlisting}


\begin{listing}
    \begin{minted}{java}
        ... input short code here ...
        ... This code will not break across pages ...
    \end{minted}
    \caption[Short Code Example]{A shorter code example which will not break across pages.}
    \label{lst:short}
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```

## Result When Filled in With of Code

[image: page1]
[image: page2]
[image: page3]

## Closing Remarks

Apologies if I have misunderstood your intent. If you truly do want to list your listings as `figure`s, you can make the following changes in my code:

Instead of

```
\newenvironment{longlisting}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
```

write:

```
\newenvironment{longlisting}{\captionsetup{type=figure}}{}
```

And for the non-breakable environments, just use `figure` as you have been doing. But as said, I would really not recommend this.

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved my life

Comment: Is that mandatory to create a new environment ? where does the `\captionsetup` command come from ?