# How to get minted listing to break into multiple pages

Tags: floats, listings, page-breaking, minted, warnings

Listings like

```
\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}[linenos,breakanywhere,breaklines]{python}
    # long code
\end{minted}
\label{lst:label}
\end{listing}
```

will go over the page number and generate a `Float too large for page by X.Xpt.` warning.

How to get that listing to span into two or more pages?

The solution using `\captionof` or defining a new environment as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12428/code-spanning-over-two-pages-with-minted-inside-listing-with-caption) isn't working well for me because I need the listing to have the same margins like the original `\listing`.

EDIT:

I need this source code

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Define Article %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Using Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{minted}
\setmintedinline{breaklines,breakanywhere}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Other Settings

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Page Setting %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\geometry{a4paper}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Define some useful colors %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{243,243,244}
\definecolor{deepGreen}{RGB}{26,111,0}
\definecolor{shallowGreen}{RGB}{235,255,255}
\definecolor{deepBlue}{RGB}{61,124,222}
\definecolor{shallowBlue}{RGB}{235,249,255}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Define an orangebox command %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\orangebox[1]{\fcolorbox{ocre}{mygray}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% English Environments %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}{3pt}{3pt}{\normalfont}{0cm}{\rmfamily\bfseries}{}{1em}{{\color{black}\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}}\thmnote{\,--\,#3}}
\newtheoremstyle{myproblemstyle}{3pt}{3pt}{\normalfont}{0cm}{\rmfamily\bfseries}{}{1em}{{\color{black}\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}}\thmnote{\,--\,#3}}
\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=1pt,backgroundcolor=shallowGreen,linecolor=deepGreen,leftmargin=0pt,innerleftmargin=20pt,innerrightmargin=20pt,]{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=1pt,backgroundcolor=shallowBlue,linecolor=deepBlue,leftmargin=0pt,innerleftmargin=20pt,innerrightmargin=20pt,]{definition}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{myproblemstyle}
\newmdtheoremenv[linecolor=black,leftmargin=0pt,innerleftmargin=10pt,innerrightmargin=10pt,]{problem}{Problem}[section]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Plotting Settings %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.9}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Title & Author %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Title}
\author{Antonio Santoro}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \begin{listing}
        \begin{minted}[linenos,breakanywhere,breaklines]{python}
        async def start(self):
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
    
        async def _handle_req(self, reader: StreamReader, writer: StreamWriter):
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
            #
        \end{minted}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{lst:server-async}
    \end{listing}
    
\end{document}
```

to be spanned into multiple pages. Right now the generated document looks like this

[image]

```
Float too large for page by 349.24756pt.
```

Comment: Try to remove the environment `listing`.

Comment: I need to use `\caption`

Comment: Can you give the formatting used? `tcolorbox + minted` can be a solution for you...

Comment: what you mean formatting?

Comment: The problem is that the environment listing seems to use a float. You can't have breaking and float at the same time.

Comment: any alternative?

Comment: Show a small example of the output expected. Give us a code that compiles.

Comment: Done, check edit

Comment: So you just want to use a caption with a `minted` breakable environment. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, basically a breakable listing, I need it to be listed too