# Figure filled with longtable

Tags: captions, longtable

I am currently creating a `figure` which is filled by `longtable` inside, why I do this is because I need the caption to be **figure**, while on the other hand, I need the `table` environment.

The thing is, the reason I use `longtable` is I will create a big table, but putting it inside a `figure` has made it unseparated. Is there a way to do this actually?

So what I already have are:
1.

```
\begin{longtable}{ccccc}
% Long content
\end{longtable}
```

This is ok, but I dont have the `Figure` caption (if it's possible to put this caption somewhere, maybe this will be an easier solution)

2.

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{longtable}{ccccc}
  % Long content
  \end{longtable}
\end{figure}
```

With this, I will have the caption, but the table will always be in a page (they don't want to be separated).

Comment: See also [Label and caption without float](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/label-and-caption-without-float).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not use a float for `longtable`, but rather the `capt-of` or `caption` package and then `\captionof{figure}{...}` to create the `Figure` caption.
Because `longtable` does increment the `table` counter by one you need to reduce it again to ensure proper numbering for following `table`s.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

% Document
\begin{center}
  \begin{longtable}{ccccc}
      a \\
  % Long content
  \end{longtable}%
  \captionof{figure}{Caption text}%
  \addtocounter{table}{-1}%
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you also have to substract 1 from the table counter. I think longtable advances it automatically but I am not a 100% sure.

Comment: @MartinH: Thanks. Yes, this is the case. I added it to my answer.

Comment: @MartinH, I think the figure caption is not properly aligned in the center!

Comment: I also tested here, and the "table" is not centered.I also tested here, and the "table" is not centered.

Comment: Just a tip: if you use ```caption``` package, you will get a starred version of ```longtable``` that does not add 1 to the table counter, so using ```longtable*``` there is no need to write ```\addtocounter{table}{-1}```.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is by using [`ltcaption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltcaption) package to redefine the float type of `longtable`, as suggested by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520472/142706).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltcaption}
\renewcommand\LTcaptype{figure} % redefine the float type used by longtable

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ccccc}
    \caption{My long table as a Figure} \\
    Test & test 2 & test 3 & test 4 & test 5\\
    Test & test 2 & test 3 & test 4 & test 5\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: One redefinition]

**Note:** There is **no need** to update the table counter with `\addtocounter{table}{-1}`.

---

#### Bonus

I am **not** sure if the following procedure causes the document to be unstable, but I was able to abuse this redefinition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltcaption}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\renewcommand\LTcaptype{figure}
\begin{longtable}{ccccc}
    \caption{My first long table as a Figure} \\
    Test & test 2 & test 3 & test 4 & test 5\\
    Test & test 2 & test 3 & test 4 & test 5\\
\end{longtable}

\renewcommand\LTcaptype{table}
\begin{longtable}{ccccc}
    \caption{My second long table as a Table} \\
    Test & test 2 & test 3 & test 4 & test 5\\
    Test & test 2 & test 3 & test 4 & test 5\\
\end{longtable}

\renewcommand\LTcaptype{figure}
\begin{longtable}{ccccc}
    \caption{My third long table as a Figure} \\
    Test & test 2 & test 3 & test 4 & test 5\\
    Test & test 2 & test 3 & test 4 & test 5\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: Many redefinitions]

Comment: Is there any way this command `\renewcommand\LTcaptype{figure}` to be local, i.e., defined inside the `figure` ambient (so we don't need to repeat it every when changing between `table` and `figure` ambients) @Leone?

Comment: @AXL I think that if we use ```figure``` environment, the whole problem of splitting the ```longtable``` across pages will return. However, you can make ```\renewcommand``` local by wrapping ```{}``` around a specific ```table```. Try putting a ```{``` right before ```\renewcommand\LTcaptype{figure}``` and a ```}``` right after```\end{longtable}```. The redefinition won't bleed out from this group restricted by the ```{}```.