# captionof in longtable gives Misplaced \noalign

Tags: captions, longtable

Trying to make a multi-page figure panel, with 50 same-sized figures in a 2-by-5 arrangement on 5 pages, a Figure caption for the entire thing at the top of the first page, and everything placed onto pages where the margin has been reduced.

With subfigure, subfig, subcaption I only got errors about "Too many unprocessed floats.", and although \usepackage{morefloats} removed the error, it also removed the figures. Switching to simple 'tabular's caused other problems, similar as with 'minipage's, where the figure panel would have to be split into one panel per page and then other floats would appear between the panels, despite many earlier \clearpage's.

With 'longtable' it almost works. But the table is not counted under Figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{cc}
    \captionof{figure}{This gives a Misplaced noalign error \label{fig:dummy1}} \\
     %\caption[This]{Works} \\
    Test & test 2 \\
    Test & test 2 \\
% later need to include this: \addtocounter{table}{-1} %
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

How to get captionof to work...?

Comment: Just put the `\captionof` *outside* the `longtable` environment. Have you tried? And why `figure`?

Comment: `longtable` has its own definition of `\caption` which makes using `\capttionof` doubly difficult: Even if you circumvent the `Misplaced \noalign`, you'll notice that the floattype `table` is hardcoded... I don't know whether it's worth it to make a complete redefinition of `longtable`s version of `\caption`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`longtable` has its own definition of `\caption` which makes using `\captionof` doubly difficult: Even if you circumvent the `Misplaced \noalign`, you'll notice that the floattype `table` is hardcoded...

As `\captionof` will always call `\caption` it's a bit hard to patch it in a way which will work inside and outside of `longtable` without completely rewriting `longtable`s version of `\caption`. Here's an idea based on `\multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\o@caption\caption
\newcommand\LT@captionof[2]
{%
  \multicolumn{\LT@cols}{p{\textwidth}}{\def\@captype{#1}\o@caption{#2}}%
}
\patchcmd\LT@array{\let\caption\LT@caption}
{\let\caption\LT@caption\let\captionof\LT@captionof}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{longtable}{cc}
    \captionof{figure}{This gives a Misplaced noalign error \label{fig:dummy1}} \\
     %\caption[This]{Works} \\
    Test & test 2 \\
    Test & test 2 \\
% later need to include this: \addtocounter{table}{-1} %
\end{longtable}

reference to figure \ref{fig:dummy1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Shameless self-advertisement: The/My `ltcaption` package (which is part of the `caption` package bundle) offers a way to re-define the float type used by `longtable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltcaption}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\LTcaptype{figure}
\begin{longtable}{cc}
    \caption{This does not give a Misplaced noalign error \label{fig:dummy1}} \\
    Test & test 2 \\
    Test & test 2 \\
% not needed: \addtocounter{table}{-1} %
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```