# Create caption without float *and* without caption package?

Tags: floats, captions, koma-script

In the appendix of my thesis, there is a large number of tables and longtables which does not need to float, as they shall appear one after the other just how they fit on the pages (and it is no problem if the bottom third of a page would stay empty).

(The appendix is structured by some headings and sometimes there is also a short paragraph or two to explain something about the data shown in the tables. So I explicitely do want to appear the tables directly and not float "elsewhere" - apart from the explaining text.)

So I thought it would be easier to let `pdflatex` typeset the tables (tabular) directly, which works well as long as I don't need captions.
But I found that I can not use the `\caption`-command in those tabulars.

This question was asked [already](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/label-and-caption-without-float), but both solutions require the use of the `caption` package which seems to be incompatible with `longtable` or `KOMA-script` classes (which I need).

So is there another way to use `\caption`s without floats?

I'm using the `KOMA-script` class `scrbook`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The package `caption` isn't incompatible with `KOMA` or `longtable`.

You don't need the package `caption` because `KOMA` provides the command `captionof`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\section{foo}
\begin{center}
\rule{3cm}{3cm}
\captionof{figure}{bla}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your hint! As I did not have installed the latest version yet (but v3.08 from Feb 2011) I did not see this apparently new feature in the manual nor does it work already. However, it produces (at least from my point of view) very strange errors, as the error during `pdflatex` compilation occurs 400 lines (in the source code) after the invalid `\captionof` command. I'll try to update to the most recent version.

Answer (score 5):

The classes of [KOMA Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) offer the `\captionof` command for captions outside floats.

```
\captionof{floattype}[List entry]{Full caption}
```

It isn't yet documented in the English version of the user guide.

Comment: How to go about when the document language is Greek? I am using for example the command   `\captionof{figure}{Δοκιμή}` successfully, though not if the greek word contains the greek final s (that is: ς).

Answer (score 3):

For LaTeX users that don't use a `KOMA-script` class, yet for some reason still don't want to load the `caption` package: There's the tiny [`capt-of`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) package that also offers the `\captionof` command.