# How to make table with caption appearing on \listoftables without \begin{table} environment?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, floats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Label and caption without float](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/label-and-caption-without-float)
>   [Create caption without float AND without caption-package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22662/create-caption-without-float-and-without-caption-package)

Here is an example of LaTeX document being compiled with `pdflatex` having

- table with caption
- hyperlinked list of tables

:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\label{mytable}
\caption{mytable}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
A & B \\
C & D \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\listoftables
\end{document}
```

How to make a table, without `\begin{table}...\end{table}`  float, preserving style of table (table having caption, label), and appearing in hyperlinked  `\listoftables` ?

(Situation: Currently I work on document where I have such tables, and I would like to put some of them without floats to force placement or tables and footnotes relating to them.)

Comment: or [label-and-caption-without-float](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/label-and-caption-without-float)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `caption.sty` you can use `\captionof{<type>}` or `\captionsetup{type=table}`.

If you want to make a new (non-floating) environment, e.g. `mytab`, i suggest to use the `\captionsetup`-way. If you want to access the captions somewhere in the document (as in you pastebin example*) `\captionof` is your friend; you may wrap it in a new command like `\tabcap`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Environment
\newenvironment{mytab}{%
    \begin{center}
    \captionsetup{type=table}
}{\end{center}}

% Shortcut
\def\tabcap{\captionof{table}}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\lipsum[1]

% Somewhere with \captionof
\begin{center}
\rule{\textwidth}{2cm}
\captionof{table}{Caption text}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

% Somewhere with shrtcut \tabcap
\begin{center}
\rule{\textwidth}{2cm}
\tabcap[Optional]{Caption text}
\end{center}

\lipsum[3]

% Environment
\begin{mytab}
\rule{\textwidth}{2cm}
\caption{Caption text}
\end{mytab}

\end{document}
```

<sub>* Please note that it’s preferred to edit your original question to add information and code and not to use external sites.</sub>

Comment: Do I get you right, that key of your answer is "use `\captionof{}{}` ? Could you ensure me that I understand you and take a look at this LaTeX toy-example http://pastebin.com/AGvmGw8J ?

Comment: This works ! :) Table is constructed 'right there' as I expected !

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: There are two keys in my answer. I improved it an hope I clarified it :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you want can be acheived with `float` package and `[H]` (meaning "here and nowhere else) placement specification. Remember that you must run LaTeX twice to get correct list of tables.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{float} %% <--- this

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H] %% <--- and this
\begin{center}
\label{mytable}
\caption{mytable}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
A & B \\
C & D \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\listoftables
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can find this post, but I've seen somewhere on this site "always provide alternative options, if you want to use only [h] - you do not want to use floats" (if someone finds post, please, leave comment). What you've point out, I ensure is "here if it fits" - according to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat . Your suggestion about "[H]" appeared earlier http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9486/7128 and it's good to mention here. However, I'm looking for "manual construction" of "table" without float.

Comment: Well, actually this is the manual construction, just it is called `{table}[H]`. the `table` environment in this case does nothing less and nothing more than 1) typeset its content in the "main flow" (meaning no floating at all), 2) make a line in the list of tables and 3) allow `\caption` command. I believe that it is exactly what you seek for.

Comment: Are you sure you have loaded the package [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float), i.e. do you have `\usepackage{float}` in your preamble?

Comment: Forgive me, I've missed it. Now, on double-checking I've found there is no package float. Thanks for help, I will remember for future.