# cannot use \caption under minipage

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, minipage

I am using following code to import two images next to each other. When `\caption{}` is used, LaTeX gives me error **caption outside float**.

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig1.eps}
\caption{text for fig1}
\label{fig:fig1}            
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig2.eps}
\caption{text for fig2}
\label{fig:fig2}            
\end{minipage}
```

When I remove the `\caption` from both places, the code compiles correctly.

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig1.eps}
\label{fig:fig1}            
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig2.eps}
\label{fig:fig2}            
\end{minipage}
```

But both the codes do not generate any label naming the figure. (something like **Figure 21**).

Am I missing anything?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22662/create-caption-without-float-and-without-caption-package

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To place a caption outside a floating environment, you can use `\captionof` from the [`capt-of`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) or [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) packages::

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig1.eps}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure}
\label{fig:fig1}            
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig2.eps}
\captionof{figure}{Some figure}
\label{fig:fig2}            
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Notice the `\noindent` and `%` character I added to prevent undesired spacing.

Comment: The command `captionof` is provided by every KOMA class, the package `capt-of` and the package `caption`

Comment: so I have to add a package using \usepackage{caption}? because as it is, it is giving undefined control sequence error.

Comment: @maths-help-seeker yes, either `caption` (as I did in my example) or `capt-of` .

Comment: @maths-help-seeker: Yes, but you can only do that in the document preamble. See [Documents with typical LaTeX errors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33472/5764).

Comment: ok thanks! it worked. It is also now showing the labels. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ... although it took me a while to find this answer ...

Comment: Although 1 question if somebody answers ... the captions of the two minipages dont have any separation ... how to introduce one because both my figures have long captions ...

Answer (score 3):

You can also wrap a figure environment around your minipage, that way you do not need to use `captionof` or `capt-of`:

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/img1.JPG}
        \caption{cap1}
        \label{fig:img1}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Images/img2}
        \caption{cap2}
        \label{fig:img2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: But this will in general allow the unit to float (despite all your `!h`).

Comment: @AndrewSwann true, my assumption was, that two images in one minipage are meant to work like one composed image, where floating may be accepted:)

Comment: using [H] with \begin{figure}[H] or \begin{table}[H] will resolve the floating issue (enabled with \usepackage{float} if I recall correctly)