# cannot scale images with latex fonts which are side by side

Tags: minipage, input

Referring to [cannot use \caption under minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57433/12894), When I use the solution provided to the question in link above, in order to include images with latex math fonts embedded into them and place them side by side, the images overlap. For this to happen I use `\input{}`
instead of `\includegraphics{}` into my code. 
The code now looks like this:

```
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \input{fig1.pstex_t}
  \captionof{figure}{fig 1}
  \label{fig:fig1}            
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \input{fig2.pstex_t}
  \captionof{figure}{fig 2}
  \label{fig:fig2}             
  \end{minipage}
```

I want to scale them to fit these correctly. Is this possible? if yes, how can I do this?

I have tried editing the `.pstex_t` files to scale the images. This does scale the images but the latex fonts get placed incorrectly outside the figure.
Using the following does not compile:

```
    \input[width = .5\textwidth]{}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you certainly will not be able to scale your images by using an optional argument to \input. If and how you can scale the images depends on the content of the files. Looking at the extension you can perhaps use `\resizebox` or `\scalebox` as described here:

http://epb.lbl.gov/xfig/latex_and_xfig.html#picsize

Comment: Thank you for directing me to this link. I will look into it.