# Create a look-like-a-figure placeholder for the printed copy of a 3d pdf

Tags: floats, 3d, printing, movie15

I managed to create and import a .u3d file using the as I just learned now obsolete movie15 package using the dokumentation (http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/movie15/doc/movie15.pdf) and this helpful page (http://rainnic.altervista.org/en/content/embed-3ds-pdf-latex-u3d?language_content_entity=en).

He managed to get a .png shown in the pdf for pdf viewers, which can not display the 3d content. I want to use this approach for the printed version of my thesis and in addition I want to display it as it would be a figure with the same look as the others with a caption. I already searched for a solution and tried several things, but didn´t came up with a satisfying solution. Could you provide one? :-)

Edit:
To answer the comment: I don't know where to put that commands, I was looking for a way to produce something like the following pseudo-code (obviously it is not working like this)

```
text={\begin{figure}
      \includegraphics[scale=1.0]{dissabbiatore.png}\caption{Caption of the figure}\label{fig:3d}
      \end{figure}},
```

Here is the MWE (How to insert it easily without hitting the spacebar on every line?):

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage[3D]{movie15}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

    \begin{document}
    Here is the original version from the \href{http://rainnic.altervista.org/en/content/embed-3ds-pdf-latex-u3d?language_content_entity=en}{tutorial}.

    \includemovie[poster,
          toolbar,
          label=pt,
          text={\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{dissabbiatore.png}},
          3Droo=6.896200246789337,
          3Daac=60.000001669652114,
          3Dcoo=0.6134188175201416 0.6502023935317993 -0.8552163243293762,
          3Dc2c=-0.8354106545448303 0.3235208988189697 -0.44432342052459717,
          3Droll=-75.5946486014902,
          3Dlights=Hard,
          3Drender=SolidOutline]
          {\linewidth}{\linewidth}{dissabbiatore_meshlab.u3d}\\
          A 3D, schematic model of a horizontal grit chamber. If the Figure does not appear interactive, please enable this function and click on it or use a recent version of \href{http://get.adobe.com/reader}{Adobe Reader}. 

          I already tried the package caption and the command captionof{figure}{Caption of the figure} resulting in an error and was not able to use the figure environment cause its a floating environment. My figures looks like this:

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{dissabbiatore.png}
        \caption{Caption of the figure}
        \label{fig:label}
    \end{figure}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: if i understand correctly, you might consider using an `\fbox` containing a zero-width `\vrule` followed by an `\hspace` of the desired width.  (start with `\noindent` to make sure they're on the same logical line.)

Comment: To highlight a block as code, select it and hit Ctrl + K, or click the button marked `{}` above the input field.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for my question could be an minipage with a `\captionof` from the caption package. Also see this question: [caption under minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57433/cannot-use-caption-under-minipage)

The following code works for me for now:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[3D]{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
The \href{http://rainnic.altervista.org/en/content/embed-3ds-pdf-latex-u3d?language_content_entity=en}{tutorial} where the idea came from.

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\includemovie[poster,
      toolbar,
      label=pt,
      text={\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{dissabbiatore.png}},
      3Droo=6.896200246789337,
      3Daac=60.000001669652114,
      3Dcoo=0.6134188175201416 0.6502023935317993 -0.8552163243293762,
      3Dc2c=-0.8354106545448303 0.3235208988189697 -0.44432342052459717,
      3Droll=-75.5946486014902,
      3Dlights=Hard,
      3Drender=SolidOutline]
      {\linewidth}{\linewidth}{dissabbiatore_meshlab.u3d}
\captionof{figure}{Caption of the figure}
\label{fig:3d}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

A 3D, schematic model of a horizontal grit chamber. If the Figure does not appear interactive, please enable this function and click on it or use a recent version of \href{http://get.adobe.com/reader}{Adobe Reader}. 
\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{dissabbiatore.png}
    \caption{Caption of the figure}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
A 3D, schematic model of a horizontal grit chamber.

\end{document}
```