# in a text and figure side by side how to add "caption" and "label"

Tags: align

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create caption without float AND without caption-package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22662/create-caption-without-float-and-without-caption-package)

i have this:

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.35\linewidth}  

Here is the text

\end{minipage}

\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.55\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{imag9}
\caption{TEXT}
\label{fig3.5}
\end{minipage}
```

When i try to  add `\caption` and `\label` (as in the figure) it shows me errors but the pdf i am taking is ok!
Is there another way to do that?

Comment: The command `caption` works only inside float environments. If you want to use a caption outside float you need the command `captionof`

Comment: If i use \captionof it shows me error "undefined control sequence \captionof".

Comment: See the link  -- you need the package `caption` or `capt-of` or a KOMA-class.

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49858/how-do-i-make-figure-captions-span-multiple-pages/51885#51885

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To label pictures outside of a figure-environment, use the caption package with the macro `captionof` like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.35\linewidth}\centering
    Here is the text
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.55\linewidth}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{image}
    \captionof{figure}{A wonderful picture}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```