# Framed text with a float in it

Tags: floats, captions, boxes, framed

I'd like to frame the text between `\startfoo` and `\stopfoo`, but there is a float in it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\startfoo

\begin{figure}[h]
some float with a \caption{...}
\end{figure}

\stopfoo
\end{document}
```

I've thought of using fancybox:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\begin{document}

\begin{Sbox}
\begin{minipage}{\hsize}
\begin{figure}[h]
some float with a \caption{...}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{Sbox}

\fbox{\TheSbox}
\end{document}
```

But this breaks due to the float inside the `minipage`, right? What can I do? The markup is fixed, I can't change it without very much labor.

Comment: You need to decide if you want to have a float or not. You can't catch a float in a box, it wouldn't be a float then. Simply place the figure in a `center` or similar environment and use `\captionof{figure}{<caption text>}` from the `caption` or (much smaller) `capt-of` package, instead of the `figure` environment, as shown in [Label and caption without float](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/label-and-caption-without-float).

Comment: What do you mean with "The markup is fixed"? Is the document generated automatically or are you including external files you can't change? In that case redefining `figure` locally would be an option.

Comment: Of course float and box contradict, but that's the way the markup currently is. So I've tried to renewcommand figure and endfigure to   `{}`, but I don't get the caption to work: http://pastebin.com/d6bYHNzt

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: the text is already there and used in other places as well, and I don't want to use all other style files "just" for this application

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to redefine the `float` environment then if you don't want to change the code of the content. The frame can be added by the `mdframed` package (or if you don't need to support page breaks also by my `adjustbox` package: `\begin{adjustbox}{fbox} <content> \end{adjustbox}`).

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{capt-of}% or caption
\usepackage{mdframed}

\let\origfigure\figure
\let\endorigfigure\endfigure

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{figurehere}[1][]{%
   \center
   \def\@captype{figure}%  see note below
}{%
   \endcenter%
}

\newcommand{\startfoo}{%
    \par\medskip
    \begin{mdframed}[linewidth=1pt]%
    \let\figure\figurehere
    \let\endfigure\endfigurehere
    \ignorespaces
}
\newcommand{\stopfoo}{%
    \unskip
    \end{mdframed}%
    \par\medskip
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
text before text before text before text before

\startfoo

text at begin of framed box
text at begin of framed box
text at begin of framed box

\begin{figure}[h]
some float with a \caption{...}
\end{figure}

text at end of framed box
text at end of framed box
text at end of framed box

\stopfoo

text after text after text after text after text after

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Note that is **NEVER** a good idea to use `{figure}[h]` (or `[H]`, `[h!]`). It is against the float concept. Always use an environment like `center` with `\captionof` instead.

In this case it is not possible to redefine `\caption` like `\def\caption{\captionof{figure}}`, because `\captionof` is `\def\@captype{#1}\caption` and would call itself then. Instead I directly set `\@captype` to `figure` and so the normal `\caption` can be used.

Comment: Following up on your discusion: Is it possible that the framed box is long enough such that the figure floats only in that restricted area ? I mean can we come up with such environments like the boxes in the magazines which support the main story?

Comment: @precusse: I'm writing on a TikZ based package which will draw frames like this without requiring to box the content, then you can simply use `\FloatBarrier` from the `placeins` package or a simple `\clearpage` if appropriate, to force the figure placing at the end (if it wasn't placed already). However, I would simply avoid the whole float-in-framed-box thing.

Comment: Wow, that is something we will look forward to it, then. So I can use it directly in my thesis. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If all you're trying to achieve is to place a framebox around a float (but not its caption), you could use the `float` package and issue the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}
```

and later on you can create figures as usual.

Comment: OK, I see that the question was not clear enough. There is more text in the framed environment besides the float. The float package/floatstyle will come in handy with another project - thanks!