# Including multiple figures/subfigures within an fbox (minipage)

Tags: floats, framed

From what I understand, it's pretty much impossible to include floats within an fbox/minipage. I basically want a paragraph of framed text with a couple of subfigures included within the frame. Any ideas as to how I might implement this?

Comment: If you don't need a floating environment just use an fbox/minipage with `\captionsetup{type=figure}` as 1st line. Afterwards `\caption`, `\subcaption(box)`, `\subfloat` etc. should work fine. (I'm assuming you are using either the `subcaption` or the `subfig` package for typesetting sub-figures.)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28412/framed-text-with-a-float-in-it

Comment: luser, please comment at least if this should be a floating environment or not.

Comment: I'm not sure if it _needs_ to be a floating environment. I need text and two side-by-side figures surrounded by a box. If this can be done without a floating environment as above, then no, it needn't be floating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For such things you can use packages like `framed`, `mdframed`, `adjustbox` or `tcolorbox`.

Every package has its own benefits and drawbacks: you can read the related documentation to get more information.

The following example uses `tcolorbox`. To provide `subfigures` I am using `subcaption`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\kant[1]
\begin{center}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{1cm}
\caption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{1cm}
\caption{B subfigure}\label{fig:2a}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{FIGURES}
\end{center}
\kant[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]