# Figures in appendix are not referenced correctly (or not the way I want them to :) )

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices

In my document, I have some figures in my appendix I want to reference in my text but the output of `\ref{}` is only "Figure .2 shows...". It should be something like "Figure B.2".

Here's my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,index=totoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
    \include{Titel}
    \tableofcontents

\mainmatter
    Here is my text \ref{fig:XYZ}

\backmatter
\appendix
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\chapter{Appendix}
\section{UML-Diagrams}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=15cm]{xyz.jpg}
    \caption{\label{fig:XYZ}XYZ}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've added the line `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` to your MWE, as it doesn't compile otherwise. The `[demo]` option replaces images with black rectangles, so compilation doesn't fail because of missing images. I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe, however. I get the output `Here is my text 1`, and the figure caption is `Figure 1: XYZ`.

Comment: Thank you for your editing! Wired that you get the semi-correct output?! I'd like to have it A.1 anyway.

Comment: Also please keep it a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), i.e. replace or remove the `\include{Titel}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You also need to redefine `\thefigure` to your own format. By default `scrbook` removes the chapter number from it outside the main matter. I assume now you actually want the section number in it.

Also note that you should use `\centering` not the `center` environment in floats like `figure`. Then `{figure}[h]` is never a good idea. If you don't want to make the figure float use an own environment (like `center` which now is OK) instead and use `\captionof{figure}{...}` for the caption (needs either the `caption` (big) or `capt-of` (small) package). Also, please put the `\label` after `\caption`, not inside it. It works both ways but this is better.

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,index=totoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}

\mainmatter
Here is my text \ref{fig:XYZ}

Here is my text \ref{fig:XYZ2}

\backmatter
\appendix
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\chapter{Appendix}
\section{UML-Diagrams}

\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=15cm]{xyz.jpg}
    \captionof{figure}{XYZ}\label{fig:XYZ}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=15cm]{xyz.jpg}
    \caption{XYZ2}\label{fig:XYZ2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jake: As always, if you know what to do you can do it. But many beginners seems to not understand the principle behind floats and try to force some Word-like behavior by default.

Comment: The renewing of the command thefigure does the job, thank you very much! A very good hint with the centering-environment, but I did not get your point :-) Could you explain it again for me? Thank you!

Comment: @strauberry: The `center` environment adds additional space before and after it, while the `\centering` macro doesn't. See [Should I use center or centering for figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures) for more infos. See also [Label and caption without float](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/label-and-caption-without-float) for the other tip I mentioned.

Comment: @MartinScharrer cool thank you! I'll have a look at your links