# How to modify the equivalent of \thefigure for listings?

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

In my appendix I have figures and listings. The figures are now labeled very well (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31794/figures-in-appendix-are-not-referenced-correctly-or-not-the-way-i-want-them-to)). Now I have the same issue with listings: in the appendix it is labeled as A.1, but in my text only as 1. What is the corresponding command to `\thefigure` I have to redefine for a listing?

Comment: See documentation of listings, section "Captions".

Comment: _everything_ is declared in the documentation of listing -> `texdoc listings`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name you're looking for is `\thelstlisting`. Example:

```
\renewcommand*{\thelstlisting}{\arabic{lstlisting}}
```

Perhaps consider using a package for customizing counters, such as chngcntr:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{chapter}}
```

This would also take care of resetting the counter at the beginning of each chapter.

Note, the counter `lstlisting` is defined at the beginning at the document, so you can work with it after `\begin{document}` or, as I showed, using `\AtBeginDocument`.

**Edit:** following Ulrikes comment: there are built-in features of the listings package for that, such as `numberbychapter=true`, you can use. However, for very consistent behavior it might be worth considering to treat the `lstlisting` counter exactly like the `figure` counters etc. in the same place of your preamble, instead of on one side customizing some counters and on the other side using similar package options.