# Number listings the same way as figures and tables

Tags: listings, numbering

For numbering figures and tables with 1 depth level like this:

```
Figure 1.2
Table 3.13
```

I use the package:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

I wanted to get the same effect for code listings usepackage `listings` but the compiler says that `chngcntr` doesnt support listings. How can I accomplish this effect? I would appreciate all help.

Comment: try `\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{CTR}{section}
\makeatother` CTR is listings counter. Please add a minimal example

Comment: @touhami: The counter of `listings` is `lstlisting` and is reset by chapter by default

Comment: Yes but it is only one number, ile 1, 2 or 3. I need the chapter number to make the first listing number and then after the dot incremented numbers like: listing 1.2, listing 1.3 etc.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How to modify the equivalent of `\thefigure` for listings?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32870/5764); [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/5764) Both of these list the suggested solution of `\usepackage{chngcntr} \AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{<section>}}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution.

The counter `lstlisting` is defined using `\AtBeginDocument` so  the change must be done after `\begin{document}`
or using `\AtBeginDocument`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{chapter}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={bla bla},label=list]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;

Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
\end{lstlisting}
\section{Foo}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={bla bla},label=list]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;

Write(’Case insensitive ’);
WritE(’Pascal keywords.’);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You example works but when I add this to my existing document i get an error `! Package chngcntr Error: chapter is not a counter.` My document template is this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316160/color-packages-change-my-spacing I dont understand which package causes conflict.

Comment: I think I got it-- I replaced parameter `chapter` in `\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{chapter}}` with `section` and it seem to work! Thank you.