# Caption out of float error when using caption

Tags: graphics, errors, captions

I'm adding captions for pictures but it shows this error :

> \caption outside float. }
>   My code is like this

```
\begin{center}
    \href{http://m.technologijos.lt/cat/7994/article/S-18917}{
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{2}\\
        \caption{Pav. 2}
    }
\end{center}
```

What is wrong here and what i should fix ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `\caption` had to be inside `figure` float environment: `\begin{figure} \includegraphics{...}\caption{...}\label{...}\end{figure}`

Comment: If you want to have a table, figure, picture with a numbered caption that stays at a fixed place, use the `caption` package. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7212/110998) for an explanation. If you are happy to use the figure or table numbering already provided by LaTeX, then `\captionof{figure}{This is the caption.}` does the job (having included `\usepackage{caption}` into the preamble).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two issues with your code:

- inside `\href` can not be nested `\caption`
- outside of `figure` `\caption{...}` cannot be used. Instead of it you can use `\captionof{figure}{...}`. For this you need to use package `caption` or `capt-of`.

Correct code for both cases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \href{http://m.technologijos.lt/cat/7994/article/S-18917}{
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{2}
    }
    \captionof{figure}{Pav. 2}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
    \href{http://m.technologijos.lt/cat/7994/article/S-18917}{
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{2}
        }
        \caption{Pav. 2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```