# forcing LaTeX to put in pictures before the text

Tags: floats, positioning

I am writing a longer article and my pictures keep getting put at the end of my article or spread around. Is there a command which forces LaTeX to compile up to that point before continuing?

```
    Voorbeelden van hoe de beren onder bepaalde apartheids gebieden.
\import{/}{pictures.tex}

\newpage
We hebben alle vier de opstellingen 500 keer laten lopen en daarvan de gemiddelde stappen en segregatie bepaald.

\begin{tabular}{|c|c c c c|}
\hline
-&\text{Lijn in het midden}&\text{1 veld lengte 4}&\text{1 veld lengte 2}&\text{2 velden lengte 3}\\
\hline
\text{stappen}&12.714&13.564&13.340&12.054\\
\text{S1 voor type groen}&93.872&99.004&91.608&91.824\\
\text{S1 voor type rood}&53.376&51.076&49.564&54.164\\
\text{S2}&19.336&15.578&21.938&19.014\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

The pictures from the imported file are currently put underneath the `tabular`.
Even though I put in a `\newpage`, I have tried using `[!ht]` and those things, but nothing worked.
Is there another solution?

Comment: Welcome, do not use a  `figure` environment i you want to control where pictures are placed. By using the environment, LaTeX controls the placement.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can only guess since you don't show us a complete document (what does your preamble look like? What does `\import` do, what is in `pictures.tex`). Y?ou have probably wrapped your pictures into `table` or `figure` environments. Remove the environment, load the package `caption` or `capt-of`, and use `\captionof{figure}{...}` instead of `\caption`.

Comment: See [Label and caption without float](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7210/110998).

Comment: @gernot in addition: If your file uses one of the KOMA-classes, the usage of the `caption`-package is not necessary. In KOMA-script the command `\captionof` already exists (as well as `\captionbelowof` and `\captionaboveof`).

Comment: @Skillmon Good point. Again the problem of the missing preamble in OP's code.

Comment: you haven't shown any relevant code so it is hard to help although `[!ht] ` makes the figure more likely to float to the end as its main effect is to prevent the figure being placed on a float page or at the bottom of a text page.

Comment: the command that flushes all pending floats is `\clearpage` so perhaps that is all the answer you need?

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `\newpage` by `\clearpage` in your fragment, then no floats will float past that point.