# \begin{figure} Your command was ignored using the slides preset

Tags: presentations, slideshow

OK. I'm truly at my wits' end.

I asked my prof. for his slides because I thought they looked really nice. He sent me the tex file and it works fine so far, however, I simply want to include a figure in there with a caption. \includegraphics{ ... ] seems to work fine but when I try to wrap it around a begin/end{figure} environment it gets ignored.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{slides}
\usepackage[centertags,reqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\topmargin -2cm \textheight 17cm \textwidth 24cm
\special{landscape}     %landscape

\newcommand{\nextslide}[1]{\end{slide}\begin{slide}{\bf \underline{\centerline{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}

\nextslide{Fun Stuff}

% Doesn't work 
%\begin{figure}[h]
%\centering
%\includegraphics{foo}
%\caption{caption}
%\end{figure}

% Does work 
\includegraphics{foo}

\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A `\begin{figure}` starts a float, which is not really useful on slides - content is supposed to be fixed, not floating. If you want captions and references you could try the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package.

Comment: This question should not have the beamer tag, imho.

Comment: @Johannes_B Already changed that :)

Comment: just use `\includegraphics{foo}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want a caption, that's the whole point. Sorry, I was not explicit about this enough. I will change this.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you, I will try your suggestion

Comment: @Marijn I do not seem able to get captionof working, would you mind writing out a small example? I get the error  " l.87 \captionof{figure}{
                        this is my caption}
If you do not understand this error, please take a closer look .." which is not very helpful. I've looked on the internet but it doesn't seem like a widly used preset (slides, instead of beamer)

Comment: that is not the whole error message, the full error probably says undefined command.  Why does it need to be a "caption" rather than just a paragraph under the image?  Note `slides` class is part of the core latex distribution but basically it is not recommended for any presentations given this century, it made sense in 1985, but less so now.

Comment: I've posted an example. However, I agree with @DavidCarlisle that the `slides` class is not the best choice for presentations (the best choice would be `beamer` for almost all purposes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using captions without a float you can use the `caption` package (see [Label and caption without float](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/label-and-caption-without-float)). To extend on that answer, an important remark is given in the `caption` documentation (currently page 18):

> [...] you should use both `\captionof` and `\captionof*` only inside boxes
>   or environments [...]

Therefore, you should either use an existing environment (such as `\begin{center} \end{center}`) or a custom environment (defined with `\newenvironment`) to indicate the scope of the caption (m.m. for boxes).

To use `\captionof`, a type must be declared with `\DeclareCaptionType`, which is unfortunately missing from the package documentation (note that the current version on CTAN is dated 2016-05-22 while the documentation is dated 2011-11-02). The identifier for the type must be chosen not to conflict with existing commands (e.g., in the MWE below the identifier `figure` generates an error while `myfigure` is ok).

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{slides}
\usepackage[centertags,reqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionType{myfigure}[Figure]
\newenvironment{nonfloat}{}{}

\topmargin -2cm \textheight 17cm \textwidth 24cm
\special{landscape}     %landscape

\newcommand{\nextslide}[1]{\end{slide}\begin{slide}{\bf \underline{\centerline{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}
\nextslide{Fun Stuff}
\begin{nonfloat}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\captionof{myfigure}{This is a figure.}
\end{nonfloat}

\end{slide}

\begin{slide}
\nextslide{Centered}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\captionof{myfigure}{This is a centered figure.}
\end{center}
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]
[image]