# Move whole inline math to new line if it is too long

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I have big tex document that was created for a4 paper, I wanted to change a4 to a5. After doing so, latex rendered some inline math in kinda awkward way:

```
Something something x + y + z =
f(x).
```

I would prefer if instead of breaking on operators and white spaces latex would move whole inline math to the new line

```
Something something
x + y + z = f(x).
```

I know I can do that **manually** with `\\` or wrap it some new environment, but it would take SO much time.

I also found this:

```
\binoppenalty=\maxdimen
\relpenalty=\maxdimen
```

but it didn't help and made things even worse because sometimes a part of the math would simply go beyond page border.

So, is there a simple and painless way to automatically move inline math to a new line instead of breaking it in awkward places?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
Something Something Something Something Something
Something 
$ x + y + z = f(x)$
\end{document}
```

[image: bad inline math breaking]

Comment: The usual method for this issue is to put the math in an \mbox{ }, but it is not at all automatic...

Comment: @Jhor That would make it go past the border as well.

Comment: What is your expected behavior? That there's a huge space between each "something" word, or that the right border is ragged on that line?

Comment: @user202729 Second one

Comment: Hm. For the first one there's [errors - Is there really no better solution to "Overfull \hbox" than adding a line break? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209229/is-there-really-no-better-solution-to-overfull-hbox-than-adding-a-line-break)

Comment: Looks like the second one isn't possible automatically? [line breaking - Avoiding hbox overflow problems by falling back to ragged text - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214463/avoiding-hbox-overflow-problems-by-falling-back-to-ragged-text)

Comment: well, that's unfortunate, guess I'll just stick to a4 then

Comment: Related question, [line breaking - How can I prevent inline math formulas from overflowing into the margin? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28818/how-can-i-prevent-inline-math-formulas-from-overflowing-into-the-margin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the penalties to prevent breaks within math then allow the white space outside math more flexibility to avoid overfull boxes

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\binoppenalty=10000
\relpenalty=10000
\sloppy

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

Something Something Something Something Something
Something 
$ x + y + z = f(x)$
\end{document}
```

Or, if you want the preceding line to be short, add white space before each math expression that can fill the line

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\binoppenalty=10000
\relpenalty=10000

\everymath{\hskip 0pt plus 1fil\penalty50\hskip 0pt plus -1fil }

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

Something Something Something Something Something
Something 
$ x + y + z = f(x)$


Something Something Something Something 
$ x + y + z = f(x)$
Something Something
\end{document}
```

Comment: From the comments this isn't really what OP is looking for though

Comment: @user202729 comments came later:-) \sloppy could be replaced by \RaggedRight  from `ragged2e` (which is generally preferable output)

Comment: @user202729 short line version added