# How to force line break in normal paragraph

Tags: line-breaking

Sometimes the paragraph will not break properly with no blank codes. How to set break automatically?
[image]

Here is example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

    Like this, the code without blanks can case this issue.

    Size(func(list(V)))<Size(list(V))Size(func(list(V)))<Size(list(V))Size(func(list(V)))<Size(list(V))Size(func(list(V)))<Size(list(V))Size(func(list(V)))<Size(list(V))Size(func(list(V)))<Size(list(V))
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the first line '<Size(list...' is not break in new line.

Comment: Please show a complete example.

Comment: This is one of the few places where a double backslash might be used to break a line in a paragraph.  The combination of fixed-width characters, few words that can be hyphenated, and almost no spaces means that there is little flexibility.  But notice that even with a forced break at that location, the line will be slightly overfull, and any changes before that point will probably require revising the break.  Another possibility is to insert `\hspace{0pt}` at that location; that should permit a break there.

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton , place double backslash and \hspace{0pt} or some blanks will make the break workaround. But if change the font size or type the words in paragraph, may change the position of double backslash manually.

Comment: The `\hspace{0pt}` won't *force* a break, but will *permit* one, so it's not as likely to require a manual adjustment if you add words or change the font size.  The particular content you've got is really hard to control (from a "western" point of view).  You might get better advice from someone used to setting han scripts.

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton for your advice.

Comment: Similar question: [line breaking - Avoiding hbox overflow problems by falling back to ragged text - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214463/avoiding-hbox-overflow-problems-by-falling-back-to-ragged-text)