# Box repeat shape of word

Tags: tcolorbox, boxes, box, adjustbox

[image]

Hi, is there any way how to make "box" follow shape of words?

Comment: Do you know the *contour* package? It's not exactly what you describe but could fit your nedds.

Comment: Thank You for the comment, yes it is close to answer, but not enough space fill between letters)

Comment: ["TeX doesn't know how the glyphs it uses look like - it only knows the bounding boxes"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27440/what-cant-tex-do#comment53699_27442)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{roboto}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\begin{document}
\roboto\huge\contourlength{.15em}
\contour{gray}{boxed}
\end{document}
```