# What are the boundaries of TeX?

Tags: pdf, tex-core

Does TeX have a limit at all? I've seen in forums that besides rendering objects with `pgfplots` and `tikz`, to animating with `animate`, to interactive PDFs by embedding `Javascript` in TeX, actually nothing is impossible in TeX that you can imagine. How can this be possible? Is there a book or script that deals exclusively with TeX and the fundamental structures?

Edit:
My question consists of two parts.

1. How can Tex as a typesetting system provide deeper layers of meaning like animations and or interaction in a PDF? Also where is the limit of TeX. Can I program chess in LaTeX? Small MiniGames that can be played in PDFs?
2. How can a wide understanding of TeX programming be achieved? This does not mean typesetting but TeX itself. Are there any books that deal with question 1, which then discuss TeX?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure what answer you are looking for, exactly? LaTeX is, above all, typesetting / text processing software, used to create professional looking documents. That said, it *is* considered Turing-complete, and thus a full-blown programming language in its own right, even if rarely the first choice for tasks outside of its core are of competence. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968411/

Comment: While there are many things you **can** do with LaTeX, that doesn't mean you **should** do them.  If it isn't typesetting, almost any other programming language would do a better job.

Comment: @Ingmar That answers the first question. So with enough effort, any conceivable program is possible to implement with TeX. If I want to study TeX, not typesetting but truly with its structures as a programming language itself, what would be the best way to start?

Comment: The TeXbok by Knuth is the best reference.  After all, he created the TeX engine.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Okay, but what programming language does a better job of embedding complex representations in PDF format than LaTeX?

Comment: To a certain extent, PDF **is** a programming language (written in ASCII with lots of MIME like blocks).  Besides, anything to do with PDF is typesetting.

Comment: @LulaTeX Are you able to distinguish between LaTeX and TeX? They are different things but you are using these words in your text like they are equal.

Comment: @wipet More or less it doesn't matter in the usage here. Formally I agree with you but LaTeX is an extension of TeX and can do what TeX can do and more.

Comment: @LulaTeX LaTeX isn't extension of TeX. LaTeX is (roughly speaking) a program written in the TeX macro language.

Comment: Dupe of [tex general - What can't TeX do? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27440/what-cant-tex-do) & [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming)

Comment: @wipet Sounds like an extention to me

Comment: Extension as in an interface layer. Also, consider `\macro{replacement text}` as diagnostic. Would that be equivalent to `substitute()` function in a spreadsheet? SAS macros produce SAS code, DCF  and TeX produce "printing" (wide sense) instructions (i.e., commands + text).  Not a language as such, more a system or method or process.

Comment: It's a bit old now, not all the images show, and the links are probably dead, but there's always https://tex-talk.net/2012/10/i-tex-therefore-i-toast/

Comment: @LulaTeX You can certainly program games in TeX.  One such example is [reverxii](https://ctan.org/pkg/reverxii), an implementation of the Reversi board game.  It is most certainly possible to program a game of chess in TeX, it just depends how “smart” you want the computer to play against the user, and how much effort you are willing to put into that.