# Minipage that allows page breaks?

Tags: page-breaking, indentation, minipage

Is there a `minipage`-like environment that allows pagebreaks? Everything I can find is about avoiding page breaks (which `minipage` does well) but I want to indent a whole section, which is convenient to do by wrapping the section in `minipage` as `\leftskip` is overtaken by the environment enclosing this section.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-change-the-margins-for-only-part-of-the-text

Comment: This question might be relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4590/splitting-a-float-with-code-listings/4682#4682

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another option is to use `adjustwidth` from the `changepage` package- see example below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Regular settings}
\lipsum

\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}
\section{Adjusted settings}
\lipsum
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

Note that the `adjustwidth` environment takes 2 arguments, the first is the indent from the left of the page, the second is the indent from the right of the page. I put `showframe=true` when I loaded the `geometry` package just for demonstration.

If you plan to use this idea at lots of different places throughout the document, it is probably worth defining your own environment, something like

```
\newenvironment{mywidth}{\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}}{\end{adjustwidth}}
```

which could then be used as

```
\begin{mywidth}
\lipsum
\end{mywidth}
```

If your document is `twosided` then you can adjust the width different for even and odd sides- see the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 8):

no need for a `minipage`, use a `trivlist`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\begin{trivlist}\leftskip=2cm
\item\relax\lipsum[1]
\end{trivlist}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works provided that no `list` based environment appears within this `trivlist`. `\begin{list}{}{\leftmargin=2cm}...\end{list}` wouldn't have this problem (and is the approach taken by `adjustwidth`).

Answer (score 2):

For completion purpose, here comes another alternative that doesn't need any aditional package. Start a group in which you put the text to have the desired margins set as follows:

```
{
\leftskip=3cm %You can also use other units of glue.
\rightskip=2cm
This text will have margins adjusted for the parameters as desired. They specify glue to be inserted at the left and right of every line in a paragraph. Breakpages happens. After the group ends, the former margins are restored. You can also create a newenvironment for various uses of this.

}
```

Plain TeX also has the `\narrower` macro, described in the TeXbook, that increases both `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` by the current `\parindent`:

```
{\narrower\smallskip
This paragraph will have narrower lines than the surrounding paragraphs do, because it uses the ``narrower'' feature of plain \TeX. The former margins will be restored after this group ends. This may be useful for quoting lengthy passages from a book.\smallskip

}
```

Note it is necessary to end the paragraph before ending the group with a blank line or a `\par`, for example, otherwise the effect disappear.

**Reference and more information**: Donald E. Knuth, The TEXbook, chapter 14 "How TeX Breaks Paragraphs into Lines".