# Definitive guide to trivlists

Tags: lists, environments

I create a lot of `theorem`-like environments, and I'm usually happy to employ a package (such as `ntheorem`, `amsthm`, etc) to do the work for me.

After studying the `ntheorem` documentation, and reading many answers here on TeX exchange, it seems that most `theorems`, and more interestingly, a lot of the 'standard' environments (such as the [`center`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering) environment, for example) are defined in terms of `trivlist`s

I'm interested in experimenting with my own environments using `trivlist`s, but would like to know all the parameters that can be tweaked- so far I haven't been able to find a definitive guide, hence this question :)

So, can someone provide details of all of the parameters that can be tweaked in order to customize a `trivlist`?

Here's a MWE that can be played with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}

\newenvironment{problem}{%
\begin{trivlist}%
\item[{\bfseries Problem}]%
\item%
}{\end{trivlist}}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Interestingly, there's no `trivlist` tag, so feel free to re-tag as you see appropriate.

Comment: Perhaps the definitions of `\trivlist`, `\@trivlist` (and related commands) in [source2e](http://ctan.org/pkg/source2e) could give you a starting point.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes indeed, section 56.1 looks very helpful- thanks

Comment: Also check out http://www.tex-tipografia.com/enumitem.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I cannot say this answer is a definitive guide, but the definitive statement one can make about `trivlists` are that they are *plain vanilla*  lists.

```
\begin{trivlist}
  \item $\varepsilon$-\TeX
  \item[test] a line to test
  \item Ghostscript, version $\ge8.31$
  \item dvipdfmx, version $\ge20080607$ for DVI to PDF conversion
  \item Adobe Reader or another viewer
\end{trivlist}
```

In simple terms the `trivlist` environment turns each item into a paragraph and thus it is easier to apply formatting information to a list of paragraphs or items if you want to think of them this way. As it carries common information to all lists, it is used to build up more complicated structures. All LaTeX's lists use `parshape` to shape the paragraph and the source is not easy to follow.

The definite guide of course is `File A: ltlists.dtx` in `source2e`.

A good use of trivlists is to simplify the writing of table heads and produce semantic table environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newenvironment{name}
  {\trivlist\item
   \tabular{@{}ll@{}}}
  {\endtabular\endtrivlist}
\begin{name}
   First    & Mary  \\
   Second   & Jones \\
   Nickname & --- \\
\end{name}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 (and accepted): `source2e` is very clear- I also studied the `changepage` package which uses `list` environments at its heart. I might post an answer giving some examples, but yours sent me to the right place- thanks!

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks. Good idea to post some examples.

Comment: Why is the `\trivlist` needed in the `name` environment at all? Simply excising it and its `\endtrivlist` pair seems to result in almost identical output.

Answer (score 17):

Yiannis provided the details of where to find the definitive guide:

```
texdoc source2e
```

Section 56 is very detailed, and provides all of the parameters that can be tweaked. I thought I'd provide a small example for future reference- perhaps it will help others creating environments. (I don't claim this answer is the definitive guide, but merely an introductory experiment that may help others.)

**Motivation**

Firstly though, the reason I am interested in `lists` and `trivlists` is to create `theorem`-like environments. In particular, I wanted to emulate the `break` style from the `ntheorem` package, which produces something like

[image]

Initially I thought that a `trivlist` would be appropriate, but referencing @egreg's comment to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32706/6621)

> This works provided that no list based environment appears within this
>   trivlist. `\begin{list}{}{\leftmargin=2cm}...\end{list}` wouldn't have
>   this problem (and is the approach taken by `adjustwidth`).

So, I then decided to use the `list` environment instead of the `trivlist`, and studied the `changepage` documentation too.

**The `list` environment**

The `list` environment has the form

```
\begin{list}{<label>}{options}
\item ...
\end{list}
```

A complete set of options is detailed in `source2e`, but I'll only go into a few of them here. For my particular application, I don't need a `<label>`, so this argument will always be empty.

- the default settings of the list environment (without any options)

  ```
      \begin{list}{}{}
        \item {\bfseries Problem}
        \item \lipsum[1]
      \end{list}
  ```

  give the following output

[image]

- note that the list is indented, and the separation between **Problem** and the next `item` is not ideal
- we can tweak a few options

  ```
    \begin{list}{}{% options
          \setlength{\leftmargin}{0mm}%     leftmargin
          \parsep\parskip%                  space between paragraphs within an item
          \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}%   space between items
     }
     \item {\bfseries Problem}
     \item \lipsum[1]
     \end{list}
  ```
- I don't want any space between my `item`s, so I pull them together using `-\parsep`, and this gives the desired result

[image]

Of course, this can be all be done in the pre-amble to make a `\newenvironment`

```
\newenvironment{problem}{\begin{list}{}{%
              \setlength{\leftmargin}{0mm}%
              \setlength{\rightmargin}{0mm}%
              \setlength{\topsep}{0mm}%
              \setlength{\partopsep}{0mm}%
              \parsep\parskip%
              \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}%
              }\needspace{\baselineskip}\item {\bfseries Problem}
              \item}{\end{list}}
```

I've used the `needspace` package which provides the command `\needspace{<space>}` to stop page breaks happening between **Problem** and the body of the environment.

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to Philippe Goutet for pointing out that the `needspace` approach is actually quite flawed; in particular, if the `problem` environment immediately follows an occurrence of `\section{}` then it could potentially widow the section heading, and start a new page- very bad! So, he proposed that I copy the definitions of `\item` and `\@item` (from `ltlists.dtx`) into some new commands called `\nobreakitem` and `\@nobreakitem` and change the `\addpenalty\@itempenalty` to `\addpenalty\@M`.

A complete MWE follows that demonstrates this in action, and in particular, demonstrates that we don't get any lonely orphaned section headings- hoorah!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% copied from ltlists.dtx
\def\nobreakitem{%
  \@inmatherr\nobreakitem
  \@ifnextchar [\@nobreakitem{\@noitemargtrue \@nobreakitem[\@itemlabel]}}
\def\@nobreakitem[#1]{%
  \if@noparitem
    \@donoparitem
  \else
    \if@inlabel
      \indent \par
    \fi
    \ifhmode
      \unskip\unskip \par
    \fi
    \if@newlist
      \if@nobreak
        \@nbitem
      \else
        \addpenalty\@beginparpenalty
        \addvspace\@topsep
        \addvspace{-\parskip}%
      \fi
    \else
      \addpenalty\@M%only new bit!
      \addvspace\itemsep
    \fi
    \global\@inlabeltrue
  \fi
  \everypar{%
    \@minipagefalse
    \global\@newlistfalse
    \if@inlabel
      \global\@inlabelfalse
      {\setbox\z@\lastbox
       \ifvoid\z@
         \kern-\itemindent
       \fi}%
      \box\@labels
      \penalty\z@
    \fi
    \if@nobreak
      \@nobreakfalse
      \clubpenalty \@M
    \else
      \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
      \everypar{}%
    \fi}%
  \if@noitemarg
    \@noitemargfalse
    \if@nmbrlist
      \refstepcounter\@listctr
    \fi
  \fi
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\makelabel{#1}}%
  \global\setbox\@labels\hbox{%
    \unhbox\@labels
    \hskip \itemindent
    \hskip -\labelwidth 
    \hskip -\labelsep
    \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\labelwidth
      \box\@tempboxa
    \else
      \hbox to\labelwidth {\unhbox\@tempboxa}%
    \fi
    \hskip \labelsep}%
  \ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{problem}{\begin{list}{}{%
            \parsep\parskip%
            \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}%
            }\item {\bfseries Problem}
            \nobreakitem}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\vspace{13.55cm} % just to simulate potential page breaks
\section{no page breaks here!}
\begin{problem}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice write up. I also added a simple example of `trivlists` above.

Comment: @cmhughes: The `\needspace` may avoid breaks between the two items, but it also introduces an unwanted break point at the start of the environment so if you use `{problem}` just after a `\section{...}` you can have your section title at the bottom of the page and your problem beginning on the top of the following page. To avoid this, you need to copy the definition of `\item` and `\@item` and make new commands `\nobreakitem` and `\@nobreakitem` in which you change `\addpenalty\@itempenalty` to `\addpenalty\@M` and then use `\nobreakitem` for your second `\item` (without the `\needspace`).

Comment: This tutorial was very helpful. Good work!