# Proof environment - line break after the "Proof."

Tags: line-breaking, theorems, amsthm

I want to make the proof environment in amsthm package to auto add a line break right after the "Proof."

I tried the following code, which also removed the QED sign, but it doesn't work: No linebreak is added.

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
    \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
    \trivlist
    \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
        #1\@addpunct{.} \newline] }%\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Did you try with ``\mbox{}\\`` *after* the closing `]` instead of `\newline` before it? Usually I advise against having "Proof" in a line by itself: it creates a lot of white space and is not necessary as the italic shape used for "Proof" already makes it prominent.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

a manual way to drop to a new line immediately after the proof heading is to insert

```
$ $\newline
```

but it's possible to build on the existing `proof` definition and thereby retain the ability to use the `\qedhere` facility to move the "tombstone" up to the actual last line of the proof.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newenvironment{myproof}[1][\proofname]{%
  \begin{proof}[#1]$ $\par\nobreak\ignorespaces
}{%
  \end{proof}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  $ $\newline
    First line of my proof

    Intermediary lines of my proof:
  \begin{itemize}
   \item next-to-last line
   \item last line of my proof
  \qedhere
  \end{itemize}
\end{proof}

\begin{myproof}[Proof of my theorem]
    First line of my proof

    Intermediary lines of my proof:
  \begin{itemize}
   \item next-to-last line
   \item last line of my proof
  \qedhere
  \end{itemize}
\end{myproof}

\begin{myproof}
    First line of my proof

    Intermediary lines of my proof:
  \begin{itemize}
   \item next-to-last line
   \item last line of my proof
  \qedhere
  \end{itemize}
\end{myproof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like how this avoids redefining the entire `proof` environment.

Comment: this could leave `Proof` orphaned on a page though...

Comment: @cmhughes -- fair point.  updated to avoid the possible break.

Comment: If I use the dirty trick `$ $\newline`, the first line is not indented. Could you help me fix this?

Answer (score 6):

I would definitely consider the [`ntheorem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/ntheorem) package for this; it has a lot of very useful pre-defined styles, including `break` which is perfect for what you want; note that this won't ever orphan your `Proof` from its body.

[image: screenshot]

```
\theoremstyle{nonumberbreak}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamondsuit}}
\theorembodyfont{}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\renewtheorem{proof}{Proof}
```

It also has a robust algorithm for assigning a `theoremmark`, which can be whatever symbol you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,standard,thmmarks]{ntheorem} 

\theoremstyle{nonumberbreak}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamondsuit}}
\theorembodyfont{}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\renewtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  Your proof goes here
  Your proof goes here
  Your proof goes here
  Your proof goes here
  Your proof goes here
  Your proof goes here
  Your proof goes here
  Your proof goes here
  Your proof goes here
  Your proof goes here
  Your proof goes here
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

For further reading, you might also like to have a look at the question and answers here [Definitive guide to trivlists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47204/definitive-guide-to-trivlists); you'll see it is all about having an environment with a heading on a new line (that won't get orphaned).

Answer (score 4):

First, I wouldn't redefine the `proof` environment.  I would just make my own.  Secondly, the placement of your `\newline` needs to be placed outside of the square brackets.  Here's a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myproof}[1][\proofname]{\par
    \pushQED{\qed}%
    \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
    \trivlist
    \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
        #1\@addpunct{.} ]\mbox{}\par\nobreak}
    {\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{myproof}
    First line of my proof

    Intermediary lines of my proof:
    \lipsum[1]

    last line of my proof
\end{myproof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But because of the `\newline` The indentation of the paragraphs doesn't look good to me.  So, I would recommend changing the `\newline` to `\par` to force a paragraph break.  So the code for the new environment would be

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myproof}[1][\proofname]{\par
    \pushQED{\qed}%
    \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
    \trivlist
    \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
        #1\@addpunct{.} ]\mbox{}\par\nobreak}
    {\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse}
\makeatother
```

which results in[image]

Comment: The `\par` allows a page break, so it may cause detaching the proof body from the heading. Probably ``\mbox{}\\*\indent`` or `\mbox{}\par\nobreak` are more sensible choices. But with or without indenting the first line the result is bad. Contrary to you, I *would* redefine the `proof` environment.

Comment: @egreg.  I agree with you about the `proof.` just  floating there by itself.  I don't think it should be on a separate line.  I'll change to code to reflect your suggestion about the use of `\par`.  I do have a question, why the `mbox`?  Why not just `\hfill` or some cousin of it?

Comment: The important thing is to start horizontal mode, so even `\leavevmode` would suffice. It's not necessary to "fill the line", as ``\\`` or `\par` are perfectly happy to break a line, provided the line has started (which it doesn't with the simple `\item[...]` command).

Comment: @egreg.  Thank you!  You've just made sense of some issues I've long been perplexed about.  It hadn't occurred to me that I had to start horizontal mode here.

Comment: this definition loses the ability to use `\qedhere`, which is useful when a proof ends with a list or a display.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I'm not familiar with `\qedhere`.  If I restore the `\pushQED{\qed}` to the beginning of the environment definition and `\popQED` to the end of it, will that fix `\qedhere`?

Comment: @A.Ellett -- i've just posted an answer showing the use of `\qedhere`, along with a redefinition of `proof` based on the existing definition that avoids mucking around with the `pushQED`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton.  Just in case someone really wants to go through the effort to rewrite the `proof` environment, I've fixed my solution so that `\qedhere` now works.  But, I think @barbarabeeton's solution is really a better one than mine.

Answer (score -2):

Summarize your proof in one line, and // at the end.

because not everyone wants to read you proof word by word to know what you are saying.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
 We prove it by contradiction.\\
 Suppose the contrary that blablabla is not true, then blabla does not exists. Contradiction.]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you please explain, how double *slash* could help to get a line break? Best would be to also show a working example to illustrate, what you are meaning. Currently this one liner seems to be not very useful and not very clear.