# Square at the end of proof without "proof" at the beginning

Tags: proof-package

I'm writing a paper and I would like to have a square at the end of each proof without having the "Proof." that comes automatically with the

```
\begin{proof}
...
\end{proof}
```

thing because I don't want the "Proof" to be in italic, and I want two dots after "Proof".

I know I can do this manually by using `\blacksquare` or something of this sort. But I want the squares to be placed automatically because there are too many proofs and it would take a lot of time to manage the spacing after each proof. So I do want to use that "\begin{proof}...\end{proof}" thing but somehow I don't want it to give "Proof." at the beginning.

Is there a way for this? And if not, what other command could I use so that black squares are placed automatically but with no "Proof." at the beginning?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, if not via `proof`, what is your desired input syntax to obtain what you want?  That is, you somehow need to indicate when to place the square.

Comment: [This message](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85081) by Barabara Beeton can be very useful to customize this type of thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... I don't want the [word] "Proof" to be in italic ... I want [a colon] after "Proof" ...

Assuming you employ the `amsthm` package to set up and typeset theorem-like environments, you may achieve your formatting objective by modifying the macros `\proofname` and `\qedsymbol`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for '\blacksquare' macro
\usepackage{amsthm}   % for 'proof' environment 
\renewcommand\proofname{\textup{Proof:}} % default is 'Proof.' 
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Bla bla bla\dots
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you