# material swapped with \subsection in AMS document classes

Tags: sectioning, framed, amsbook

I today saw very interesting case when subsection started by shaded environment

```
\documentclass{amsbook}%{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newenvironment{Shaded}{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep1pt \colorbox{shadecolor}}%
  \MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{ShadedTheorem}
{
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.94,.96,.94}%
\begin{Shaded}%
\begin{theorem}%
}{%
\end{theorem}%
\end{Shaded}%
}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Bad Subsection}
\begin{ShadedTheorem}
        Bad Theorem: is moved
\end{ShadedTheorem}

\subsection{Okay without shading}
\begin{theorem}
        Good theorem
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Subsection with text first}
Okay if shaded theorem is not the first object
\begin{ShadedTheorem}
        Theorem Statement
\end{ShadedTheorem}

\subsection{Subsection with space first OK}~
\begin{ShadedTheorem}
        Theorem Statement
\end{ShadedTheorem}

\subsection{Subsection with \texttt{\textbackslash par} first: not okay}\par
\begin{ShadedTheorem}
        Theorem Statement
\end{ShadedTheorem}

\subsection{Subsection, leave vertical mode first, then enter vertical mode again.}\leavevmode\par
\begin{ShadedTheorem}
        Theorem Statement
\end{ShadedTheorem}

\end{document}
```

In all cases the shaded theorem should appear after the section heading. But that's not what the output shows.

[image]

In general as you can see there is way around. However somebody may see similar case and need some solution. Also may be there are solution different from what I found

Comment: Can you specify what you are getting at? As I see it, there is neither an issue nor a question. The code you provided compiles without errors or warnings and looks fine to me. What is this "interesting case" you are refering to?

Comment: @MarkusG. Theorem 1.2 somehow ends up printed ABOVE the second subsection, even though it is issued after the `\subsection`.

Comment: Second subsection should start from theorem. But theorem precedes subsection and subsection starts from the proof

Comment: I haven't checked this, but I believe that a `\subsection` is meant to be run in.  Thus it is assuming that the theorem statement is an implicit "argument" of `\subsection`.  If that is indeed the case, adding `\leavevmode` or `$ $` before the theorem should correct the order.  (I will be offline for a few hours, and don't have time to check this now.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton you are of course correct. (See both the 6th section in the MWE above and my follow up question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597762/why-is-startsection-defined-this-way-and-is-there-a-way-to-fix-it?noredirect=1&lq=1.) I take it from your comment that "doing something to leave v mode" **is** what one should do in this case?

Comment: @WillieWong -- "of course" is a bit strong, but thanks for your confidence.  `\leavevmode` is something I've taken on faith, not understanding how it works well enough to explain.  But after poking around, I like the solution I proposed here: [Proof environment - line break after the “Proof.”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85059)  It avoids a possible break after the heading at the end of a page.

Comment: @barbarabeeton When I started my paper more then year, I used theorem environment and everything was good. I did not return to specific place for diff equations for long time. because I believed that I finished there.  This winter I decided to use frame package to highlight theorems. When I see that everything works as expected, I made global change in my text. Few days ago I decided to add few theorems for diff equations and returned to place which I finished year ago. To my surprise I discovered that I lost theorem and section started from prove. The rest was experiment with code