# Adding vertical space between theorem numbering line and theorem text

Tags: vertical-spacing

When using `\begin{theorem}` with `amsmath`, the theorem text is inserted on the same line.  I would like to have the text in a new paragraph

Have thought about using `\vspace` and use a pre-defined vertical spacing.  Have seen that the value of `\parskip` is 0pt.  What other predefined separator can I use?

Notwithstanding, `\vspace` is not inserting a newline.

```latex
    \begin{theorem}[{\bf \color{blue} Convolution Property of Fourier Transform}]
      \label{convolution}
    
      \vspace{5pt}
      \textcolor{blue}{This text in not placed as a new paragraph.}
    
    \end{theorem}
```

Comment: It depends on what packages you are using and document class, different packages or classes can alter it. In plain TeX, it is apparently `\parskip=0pt plus1pt` or so the TeXbook says (p. 104). Please clarify your question including what class etc

Comment: I am using `\documentclass{book}`.

Comment: The value of `\parskip` is `\parskip`. So `\vspace{\parskip}` or what else have you in mind?

Comment: You should clarify your question. As Peter says, you can do `\vspace{\parskip}` but in book that has a natural size of 0pt so why would you need his?

Comment: Also, if you're adding `\vspace`, you should do it only when you're in vertical mode; otherwise, where it's actually applied may surprise you.

Comment: I am using `\begin{theorem}` and want to have some small vertical space between the theorem numbering, and the theorem text.

Comment: (1) Theorems have nothing to do with `amsmath`.  (2) The theorem environment is defined to begin in horizontlal mode after the header.  To get to a new line, you have to break into vertical mode.  (3) Although this q/a refers to a `proof` environment and uses `amsthm`, the tactics described here will also apply to the `theorem` environment: [Proof environment - line break after the “Proof.”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85059)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is producing the following output:

[image]

Using `\medskip` etc within the environment wouldn't work nor would using it after the command `\\` so instead a custom command named `\custskip` was defined to do as you seek, you can change the `6pt` to whatever you would like. As an aside, `\bf` is quite old so you should use the new commands either `\textbf` for text in an argument and `\bfseries` as a switch (i.e. all the text afterwards is bold).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand\custskip{\\[6pt]}

\begin{document}

    \begin{theorem}[{\color{blue}\textbf{Convolution Property of Fourier Transform}}]
      \label{convolution}
      
      \textcolor{blue}{\custskip This text in now placed as a new paragraph.}
    
    \end{theorem} 
    
\end{document}
```

Not sure if this is the best or most accurate method but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that quite easily with the `ntheorem` package, which defines a `break` style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, thref, amsmath]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[{\color{blue} Convolution Property of Fourier Transform}]
  \label{convolution}
  \textcolor{blue}{This text is placed as a new paragraph.}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]