# Help with generalized list

Tags: spacing, lists, indentation

I want to create an environment which contains a list to typeset auto-numbered thesis (just like one does with math formulae). I would like the spacing to be something like this:

[image: exhibit1]

This is the code I've managed to create:

```
\newenvironment*{Tesis}
  {\begin{list}
    {\hspace{14pt}(T\arabic{tesisc})}
    {\setlength{\rightmargin}{0cm}%
     \refstepcounter{tesisc}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{2\parindent}}
    \item
  }
  {\end{list}}
```

which unfortunately renders thus:

[image: exhibit2]

I've fiddled with every `list` parameter I know of (`\labelwidth` etc.), but with no avail.

How can I tweak the `list` environment to accomplish the desired effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) is king of lists and provides a flexible interface:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{enumitem,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[label={(T\arabic*)},leftmargin=4em]
  \item \lipsum[2]
  \item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

There are numerous examples on this site using [enumitem](/questions/tagged/enumitem), but the go-source would be the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf). It also includes some examples.

Comment: It works brilliantly, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely use the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) package for this, but just in case you want a working version of your snippet, you can use the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{tesisc}
\newenvironment*{Tesis}
  {\begin{list}
    {(T\arabic{tesisc})}
    {\setlength{\rightmargin}{0cm}%
     \refstepcounter{tesisc}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{1cm}}
    \item
  }
  {\end{list}}

% for references
\renewcommand{\thetesisc}{(T\arabic{tesisc})}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{Tesis}
\lipsum[2]
\end{Tesis}
\begin{Tesis}\label{test}
\lipsum[2]
\end{Tesis}

Reference: \ref{test}

\end{document}
```

For further reading, have a look at Section 56 of [`source2e`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/source2e). Some examples are discussed in [Definitive guide to trivlists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47204/definitive-guide-to-trivlists)

Comment: Thanks, @cmhughes. I'll have a look at the references you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Using Werner's and cmhughes' answer, I came up with this code, which works fine for my purposes:

```
\newcounter{tesisc)
\newenvironment*{Tesis}
  {\begin{enumerate}%
      [label={(T\arabic{tesisc})},%
      leftmargin=4em]
     \refstepcounter{tesisc}\item
  }
  {\end{enumerate}}
```

Comment: You can clone the basic lists to create your own - probably very similar to what you're doing. See section **7 Cloning the basic lists** in the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf). Not sure why you're using `\refstepcounter` though, since `\item` should `\refstepcounter{tesisc}`...

Comment: If I don't specify `\refstepcounter{tesisc}` my count remains in 0.

Comment: Then your use is probably `\begin{Tesis} something \end{Tesis}` rather than `\begin{Tesis} \item something \end{Tesis}`?

Comment: Indeed, but I still require the `\refstepcounter{tesisc}` command.