# environment without line breaks

Tags: line-breaking, linguistics

I already read [How can I prevent breaks in a custom environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126790/how-can-i-prevent-breaks-in-a-custom-environment/126794?noredirect=1#comment1290375_126794) but this somehow does not solve my problem. I want to define an environment that defines a heading and then there is one line of text and a huge AVM. All of this has to stay on the same page. I tried samepage but LaTeX is stubborn and breaks anyway. I tried minipage but then the space before and after the environment is gone.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{schema}
\newenvironment{schema}[1][]
  {% \begin{schema}[<title>]
  \goodbreak%
  \refstepcounter{schema}%
  \begin{list}{}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}\setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}\setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}}%
    \item[{\textbf{Schema~\theschema}}]\hspace{.5em}\textbf{(#1)}\nopagebreak[4]\par\nobreak}%
  {\end{list}}% \end{schema}

\newcommand{\onems}[2][]{%
  \mbox{%
    \delimiterfactor=1000 \delimitershortfall=0pt
    \tabcolsep=0pt
    $\left[%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    {\normalfont\itshape #1}%
    \\ 
    \fi
    #2%
    \end{tabular}%
    \right]$%
  }%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{schema}[Head-Complement Schema]
\label{schema-hc-flat}
\textit{head-complement-phrase}\\*
\onems{
synsem|loc|cat|comps <>\\
head-dtr       \onems{ synsem|loc|cat|comps 1\\
                   }\\
non-head-dtrs synsem2signs(1)\\
}
\end{schema}

\end{document}
```

Edit: This is the version of the code with minipage wrapper (commented out). The minipage version eats the space before and after the environment. I do not know how to fix this.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{array,lipsum}

\newcounter{schema}
\newenvironment{schema}[1][]
  {% \begin{schema}[<title>]
  \goodbreak%
  \refstepcounter{schema}%
  \begin{list}{}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}\setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}\setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}}%
    \item[{\textbf{Schema~\theschema}}]\hspace{.5em}\textbf{(#1)}\nopagebreak[4]\par\nobreak}%
  {\end{list}}% \end{schema}

%% \newenvironment{schema}[1][]
%%   {% \begin{schema}[<title>]
%%   \goodbreak%
%%   \refstepcounter{schema}%
%%   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
%%   \begin{list}{}{\setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}}%
%%     \item[{\textbf{Schema~\theschema:}}]#1\par\nobreak}%
%%   {\end{list}\end{minipage}}% \end{schema}



\newcommand{\onems}[2][]{%
  \mbox{%
    \delimiterfactor=1000 \delimitershortfall=0pt
    \tabcolsep=0pt
    $\left[%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    {\normalfont\itshape #1}%
    \\ 
    \fi
    #2%
    \end{tabular}%
    \right]$%
  }%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{schema}[Head-Complement Schema]
\label{schema-hc-flat}
\textit{head-complement-phrase}\\*
\onems{
synsem|loc|cat|comps <>\\
head-dtr       \onems{ synsem|loc|cat|comps 1\\
                   }\\
non-head-dtrs synsem2signs(1)\\
}
\end{schema}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The only sensible way to force everything in a block is to use `minipage` or `\parbox`. You say you "tried minipage but then the space before and after the environment is gone". It would be best you posted _this_ MWE and we can take it from there.

Comment: I added the minipage version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment, IMO the only sensible way to avoid a page break at all costs is to put the content in a `minipage` or `\parbox`. The spacing before and after the `minipage` can be added with an explicit `\bigskip` (or `\medskip`, or whatever you find pleasant). A little care is needed for the spacing *after* the environment, but here the kernel macro `\@endparenv` comes in handy.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{array,lipsum}

\newcounter{schema}
  
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{schema}[1][]
  {%
   \refstepcounter{schema}%
   \par\bigskip\noindent
   \minipage{\linewidth}%
   \textbf{Schema~\theschema: \ifx&#1&\else(#1)\fi}\par
  }{\endminipage\par\bigskip\@endparenv}%
\makeatother


\newcommand{\onems}[2][]{%
  \mbox{%
    \delimiterfactor=1000 \delimitershortfall=0pt
    \tabcolsep=0pt
    $\left[%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    {\normalfont\itshape #1}%
    \\ 
    \fi
    #2%
    \end{tabular}%
    \right]$%
  }%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]
\begin{schema}[Foo]
\label{foo}
\textit{head-complement-phrase}\\*
\onems{
synsem|loc|cat|comps <>\\
head-dtr       \onems{ synsem|loc|cat|comps 1\\
                   }\\
non-head-dtrs synsem2signs(1)\\
}
\end{schema}
See schemes \ref{foo} and \ref{baz}.
\lipsum[66]
\begin{schema}[Baz]
\label{baz}
\textit{head-complement-phrase}\\*
\onems{
synsem|loc|cat|comps <>\\
head-dtr       \onems{ synsem|loc|cat|comps 1\\
                   }\\
non-head-dtrs synsem2signs(1)\\
}
\end{schema}

\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The advantage of closing the environment with `\@endparenv` is that the indentation after `\end{schema}` is suppressed unless you leave an explicit empty line.

(I assume you noticed that with small caps you get `<>` but the `|` is rendered as an em-dash. I hope you know what you are doing there `:-)`.)