# Prevent linebreak before enumerate

Tags: line-breaking, enumerate

I switched from a `proof` environment to a custom one, if I begin the custom environment with an `enumerate`, there is a linebreak that I'd like to prevent. The MWE shows the difference between the `proof` environment and `ex`. I tried playing with spacings, and `/nobreak`, to no avail.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

%% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[matha,mathb]{mathabx}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage[french]{babel} % load last

%% Custom environments/macros
\newcounter{exnum}[section]
\newenvironment{ex}
           {\stepcounter{exnum}\paragraph{Exercice \thesection.\theexnum.}}
           {\hfill\(\Box\)}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{ex}
  \begin{enumerate}[(a),wide=0pt]
    \item foo
  \end{enumerate}
\end{ex}

\begin{proof}
  \begin{enumerate}[(a),wide=0pt]
    \item foo
  \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an acceptable solution?  The line is not being broken after the item in the trivlist (actually, the solution is stolen from the amsthm)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

%% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[matha,mathb]{mathabx}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage[french]{babel} % load last

%% Custom environments/macros
\newcounter{exnum}[section]

\newenvironment{ex}
       {\stepcounter{exnum}%
        \trivlist\item[\bfseries Exercice \thesection.\theexnum.]\ignorespaces}
       {\hfill\(\Box\)\endtrivlist}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{ex}
  \begin{enumerate}[(a),wide=0pt]
  \item foo
  \end{enumerate}
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this works very well. I should've looked for the source code of the `proof` environment. There seems to be quite a bit to do with trivlists, especially when  [defining custom theorem-like environments.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47204/definitive-guide-to-trivlists) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke the `inline` option to `enumitem`, then using `enumerate*` instead of `enumerate` gives you inline lists:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

%% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[matha,mathb]{mathabx}
\usepackage[shortlabels,inline]{enumitem}

\usepackage[french]{babel} % load last

%% Custom environments/macros
\newcounter{exnum}[section]
\newenvironment{ex}
           {\stepcounter{exnum}\paragraph{Exercice \thesection.\theexnum.}}
           {\hfill\(\Box\)}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{ex}
  \begin{enumerate*}[(a),wide=0pt]
    \item foo
  \end{enumerate*}
\end{ex}

\begin{proof}
  \begin{enumerate}[(a),wide=0pt]
    \item foo
  \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This would be a good workaround if the items are small, but in my case (which I did not specify), they are not. Also, I'd prefer for the following items to be on a new line rather than inline. Sorry for not being specific enough.