# Typeset a biblatex bibliography in a cv4tw CV

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking, minipage, cv

I'm using the [`cv4tw`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cv4tw?lang=en) package to produce a CV.  This package provides a `\story` command for typesetting individual CV entries; one of its arguments is a label which appears on the left, and most of the other arguments get typeset to the right of that label.  Both the left- and right-hand parts are set inside `minipage` environments.

I need to include several long publication lists in the CV, for which I use biblatex's `\printbibliography` inside a `\story` command (or my own simplified adaptation of it shown below).  The problem is that the `minipage` environment in which the bibliography appears doesn't allow page breaks.  If a publication list is too long for the page, the whole thing gets pushed to the next page, and even then the whole list may not fit on the page.

How can I typeset bibliographies in a `cv4tw` document such that they match the default `\story` style, but allow bibliographies to be automatically broken across pages?  I am thinking that the best way to do it would be to define a list-like environment which emulates the look of `\story`, though everything I've tried (such as adapting the `cvlist` environment from the `currvita` package) results in strange spacing.

Here is a minimal working example showing the problem.  (The `\publist` command is an adaptation of the default `\story` command.)

```
\RequirePackage[bibstyle=authoryear,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{cv4tw}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
\usetheme[minuit]{sharp}\firstname{John}\lastname{Doe}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% Publication list, modelled after cv4tw's \story command
\newcommand*{\publist}[2]{
  \begin{flushleft}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvleftwidth}
      {\mystyle[cvstorydatelocation] #1}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvrightwidth}
      \vspace*{-0.7em}
      \begin{refsection}%
        \nocite{#2}%
        \begin{sloppypar}%
          \mystyle[cvstoryshort]%
          \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\mystyle[cvstoryshort]}%
          \printbibliography[heading=none]%
        \end{sloppypar}%
      \end{refsection}%
    \end{minipage}
  \end{flushleft}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Publications}
\publist{Refereed journal articles}{markey,cotton,cicero,brandt,wilde,shore,salam,reese,pines,moore,massa,maron,jaffe,iliad,hyman,doody,aksin,yoon,geer}
\publist{Articles in refereed conference proceedings}{markey,cotton,cicero,brandt,wilde,shore,salam,reese,pines,moore,massa,maron,jaffe,iliad,hyman,doody,aksin,yoon,geer}
\publist{Articles I wrote just for the heck of it}{markey,cotton,cicero,brandt,wilde,shore,salam,reese,pines,moore,massa,maron,jaffe,iliad,hyman,doody,aksin,yoon,geer}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no direct answer but the following links might be helpful perhaps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271410/how-to-make-minipage-spanning-multiple-pages https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245937/minipage-with-page-break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose one hackish way might be along these lines:

```
\newlength\cvleftbibindent
\setlength{\cvleftbibindent}{\dimexpr \cvleftwidth + \bibindent\relax}

\newcommand{\xpublist}[2]{%
  \begin{sloppypar}% as in original
      \begin{refsection}
        \nocite{#2}
        \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\mystyle[cvstoryshort]}%
        \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
        {\list
          {}
          {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\cvleftbibindent}%
            \setlength{\itemindent}{-15pt}% <-- change as needed
            \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
            \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
        {\endlist}%
        {\item}%
        \raisebox{-1.65\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
          \parbox[t][0pt]{\cvleftwidth}{%
            \raggedright\mystyle[cvstorydatelocation] #1}}%
        \nobreak
        \printbibliography[heading=none]%
      \end{refsection}
  \end{sloppypar}
}
```

I say hackish because of how the 'headings' are set (viz, in an ad hoc manner). However, it works as far as I can tell.

Complete example:

```
\RequirePackage[bibstyle=authoryear,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{cv4tw}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
\usetheme[minuit]{sharp}\firstname{John}\lastname{Doe}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% Publication list, modelled after cv4tw's \story command
\newcommand*{\publist}[2]{
  \begin{flushleft}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvleftwidth}
      {\mystyle[cvstorydatelocation] #1}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvrightwidth}
      \vspace*{-0.7em}
      \begin{refsection}%
        \nocite{#2}%
        \begin{sloppypar}%
          \mystyle[cvstoryshort]%
          \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\mystyle[cvstoryshort]}%
          \printbibliography[heading=none]%
        \end{sloppypar}%
      \end{refsection}%
    \end{minipage}
  \end{flushleft}
}

\newlength\cvleftbibindent
\setlength{\cvleftbibindent}{\dimexpr \cvleftwidth + \bibindent\relax}

\newcommand{\xpublist}[2]{%
  \begin{sloppypar}% as in original
      \begin{refsection}
        \nocite{#2}
        \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\mystyle[cvstoryshort]}%
        \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
        {\list
          {}
          {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\cvleftbibindent}%
            \setlength{\itemindent}{-15pt}% <-- change as needed
            \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
            \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
        {\endlist}%
        {\item}%
        \raisebox{-1.65\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
          \parbox[t][0pt]{\cvleftwidth}{%
            \raggedright\mystyle[cvstorydatelocation] #1}}%
        \nobreak
        \printbibliography[heading=none]%
      \end{refsection}
  \end{sloppypar}
}


\begin{document}
\section{Publications}
\publist{Refereed journal articles}{markey,cotton,cicero,brandt,wilde,shore,salam,reese,pines,moore,massa,maron,jaffe,iliad,hyman,doody,aksin,yoon,geer}
\publist{Articles in refereed conference proceedings}{markey,cotton,cicero,brandt,wilde,shore,salam,reese,pines,moore,massa,maron,jaffe,iliad,hyman,doody,aksin,yoon,geer}
\publist{Articles I wrote just for the heck of it}{markey,cotton,cicero,brandt,wilde,shore,salam,reese,pines,moore,massa,maron,jaffe,iliad,hyman,doody,aksin,yoon,geer}


\xpublist{Refereed journal articles}{markey,cotton,cicero,brandt,wilde,shore,salam,reese,pines,moore,massa,maron,jaffe,iliad,hyman,doody,aksin,yoon,geer}
\xpublist{Articles in refereed conference proceedings}{markey,cotton,cicero,brandt,wilde,shore,salam,reese,pines,moore,massa,maron,jaffe,iliad,hyman,doody,aksin,yoon,geer}
\xpublist{Articles I wrote just for the heck of it}{markey,cotton,cicero,brandt,wilde,shore,salam,reese,pines,moore,massa,maron,jaffe,iliad,hyman,doody,aksin,yoon,geer}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your `\xpublist` leads with too much vertical space as compared to `\story` and my `\publist`, but that's easily fixed by adding something like `\vspace*{-4ex}` to the beginning of the command definition.