# Change margins for part of text using twosided memoir

Tags: margins, page-breaking, memoir, adjustwidth

I have a twosided document in memoir, where I want a part of the text to be centered with even margins.
As suggested in other questions, I can do this using either [changemargin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-change-the-margins-for-only-part-of-the-text), [adjustwith](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32704/minipage-that-allows-page-breaks?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [fullwidth](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fullwidth?lang=en), but all these solutions break, when text is crossing two pages, e.g. changing from even to odd page or vice versa.

Below is a MWE showing the problem.

```
\documentclass[final,twoside,onecolumn,11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\setlrmarginsandblock{25mm}{70mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]
\strictpagecheck

\usepackage{blindtext}

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 

\usepackage{fullwidth}

\begin{document}
\section{ChangeMargin}
    \begin{changemargin}{0mm}{-45mm}
        \blindtext[10]
    \end{changemargin}
\section{Adjustwidth}   
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{0mm}{-45mm}
        \blindtext[10]
    \end{adjustwidth*}
\section{Fullwidth}
    \begin{fullwidth}[twosidemode,outermargin=0mm,innermargin=5mm]
        \blindtext[10]
    \end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If that's an option for you you could drop `memoir`'s page setup and use `geometry` and its `\newgeometry` mechanism.